# Filter pandas DataFrame by substring criteria

Tags: python, pandas, regex, string, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame with a column of string values. I need to select rows based on partial string matches.

Something like this idiom:

```py
re.search(pattern, cell_in_question)
```

returning a boolean. I am familiar with the syntax of `df[df['A'] == "hello world"]` but can't seem to find a way to do the same with a partial string match, say `'hello'`.

Answer (score 1394):

[Vectorized string methods (i.e. `Series.str`)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#string-methods) let you do the following:

```
df[df['A'].str.contains("hello")]
```

This is available in pandas [0.8.1](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.8.1.html) and up.

Comment: How do we go about "Hello" and "Britain" if I want to find them with "OR" condition.

Comment: Since str.* methods treat the input pattern as a regular expression, you can use `df[df['A'].str.contains("Hello|Britain")]`

Comment: Is it possible to convert `.str.contains` to use [`.query()` api](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html#pandas.DataFrame.query)?

Comment: @zyxue [Select rows by partial string query with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44933071/395857)

Comment: `df[df['value'].astype(str).str.contains('1234.+')]` for filtering out non-string-type columns.

Comment: What about "AND" condition - how do you look for multiple strings on the same time, so not just `"hello"`, but `["hello", "hey", "hi"]`?

Comment: to "AND" substrings when the order of substrings is important/known, you could use `df[df.A.str.contains("STR1.*STR2")]`. if order is unimportant/unknown, `df[df.A.str.contains("STR1") & df.A.str.contains("STR2")]`

Comment: @NeStack I've added more information about multiple substring searches [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55335207/4909087).

Comment: If there are nulls in the column, one must also include the flag to ignore these (if desired): `df[df['A'].str.contains("hello", na=False)]`

Comment: how to apply if else e.g if contains ;dothis else do this

Comment: As for now (pandas `1.3.4`), this throws an error `cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values`, only the above solution posted by @sharon works.

Answer (score 381):

I am using pandas 0.14.1 on macos in ipython notebook. I tried the proposed line above:

```py
df[df["A"].str.contains("Hello|Britain")]
```

and got an error:

> cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values

but it worked perfectly when an "==True" condition was added, like this:

```py
df[df['A'].str.contains("Hello|Britain")==True]
```

Comment: `df[df['A'].astype(str).str.contains("Hello|Britain")]` worked as well

Comment: Another solution would be:
```
df[df["A"].str.contains("Hello|Britain") == True]
```

Answer (score 314):

> #### How do I select by partial string from a pandas DataFrame?

This post is meant for readers who want to

- search for a substring in a string column (the simplest case) as in `df1[df1['col'].str.contains(r'foo(?!$)')]`
- search for multiple substrings (similar to [`isin`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19960077/4909087)), e.g., with `df4[df4['col'].str.contains(r'foo|baz')]`
- match a whole word from text (e.g., "blue" should match "the sky is blue" but not "bluejay"), e.g., with `df3[df3['col'].str.contains(r'\bblue\b')]`
- match multiple whole words
- Understand the reason behind "ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values" and correct it with `str.contains('pattern',na=False)`

...and would like to know more about what methods should be preferred over others.

(P.S.: I've seen a lot of questions on similar topics, I thought it would be good to leave this here.)

> **Friendly disclaimer**, this is post is *long*.

---

#### Basic Substring Search

```
# setup
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['foo', 'foobar', 'bar', 'baz']})
df1

      col
0     foo
1  foobar
2     bar
3     baz
```

[`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) can be used to perform either substring searches or regex based search. The search defaults to regex-based unless you explicitly disable it.

Here is an example of regex-based search,

```
# find rows in `df1` which contain "foo" followed by something
df1[df1['col'].str.contains(r'foo(?!$)')]

      col
1  foobar
```

Sometimes regex search is not required, so specify `regex=False` to disable it.

```
#select all rows containing "foo"
df1[df1['col'].str.contains('foo', regex=False)]
# same as df1[df1['col'].str.contains('foo')] but faster.
   
      col
0     foo
1  foobar
```

Performance wise, regex search is slower than substring search:

```
df2 = pd.concat([df1] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

%timeit df2[df2['col'].str.contains('foo')]
%timeit df2[df2['col'].str.contains('foo', regex=False)]

6.31 ms ± 126 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
2.8 ms ± 241 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Avoid using regex-based search if you don't need it.

**Addressing `ValueError`s**
Sometimes, performing a substring search and filtering on the result will result in

> ```
> ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values
> ```

This is usually because of mixed data or NaNs in your object column,

```
s = pd.Series(['foo', 'foobar', np.nan, 'bar', 'baz', 123])
s.str.contains('foo|bar')

0     True
1     True
2      NaN
3     True
4    False
5      NaN
dtype: object


s[s.str.contains('foo|bar')]
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
```

Anything that is not a string cannot have string methods applied on it, so the result is NaN (naturally). In this case, specify `na=False` to ignore non-string data,

```
s.str.contains('foo|bar', na=False)

0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool
```

**How do I apply this to multiple columns at once?**
The answer is in the question. Use [**`DataFrame.apply`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
# `axis=1` tells `apply` to apply the lambda function column-wise.
df.apply(lambda col: col.str.contains('foo|bar', na=False), axis=1)

       A      B
0   True   True
1   True  False
2  False   True
3   True  False
4  False  False
5  False  False
```

All of the solutions below can be "applied" to multiple columns using the column-wise `apply` method (which is OK in my book, as long as you don't have too many columns).

If you have a DataFrame with mixed columns and want to select only the object/string columns, take a look at [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html).

---

#### **Multiple Substring Search**

This is most easily achieved through a regex search using the regex OR pipe.

```
# Slightly modified example.
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['foo abc', 'foobar xyz', 'bar32', 'baz 45']})
df4

          col
0     foo abc
1  foobar xyz
2       bar32
3      baz 45

df4[df4['col'].str.contains(r'foo|baz')]

          col
0     foo abc
1  foobar xyz
3      baz 45
```

You can also create a list of terms, then join them:

```
terms = ['foo', 'baz']
df4[df4['col'].str.contains('|'.join(terms))]

          col
0     foo abc
1  foobar xyz
3      baz 45
```

Sometimes, it is wise to escape your terms in case they have characters that can be interpreted as [regex metacharacters](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#matching-characters). If your terms contain any of the following characters...

```
. ^ $ * + ? { } [ ] \ | ( )
```

Then, you'll need to use [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) to *escape* them:

```
import re
df4[df4['col'].str.contains('|'.join(map(re.escape, terms)))]

          col
0     foo abc
1  foobar xyz
3      baz 45
```

`re.escape` has the effect of escaping the special characters so they're treated literally.

```
re.escape(r'.foo^')
# '\\.foo\\^'
```

---

#### **Matching Entire Word(s)**

By default, the substring search searches for the specified substring/pattern regardless of whether it is full word or not. To only match full words, we will need to make use of regular expressions here—in particular, our pattern will need to specify word boundaries (`\b`).

For example,

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['the sky is blue', 'bluejay by the window']})
df3

                     col
0        the sky is blue
1  bluejay by the window
```

Now consider,

```
df3[df3['col'].str.contains('blue')]

                     col
0        the sky is blue
1  bluejay by the window
```

v/s

```
df3[df3['col'].str.contains(r'\bblue\b')]

               col
0  the sky is blue
```

---

#### **Multiple Whole Word Search**

Similar to the above, except we add a word boundary (`\b`) to the joined pattern.

```
p = r'\b(?:{})\b'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, terms)))
df4[df4['col'].str.contains(p)]

       col
0  foo abc
3   baz 45
```

Where `p` looks like this,

```
p
# '\\b(?:foo|baz)\\b'
```

---

#### A Great Alternative: Use [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)!

Because you can! [And you should!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028199/for-loops-with-pandas-when-should-i-care) They are usually a little bit faster than string methods, because string methods are hard to vectorise and usually have loopy implementations.

Instead of,

```
df1[df1['col'].str.contains('foo', regex=False)]
```

Use the `in` operator inside a list comp,

```
df1[['foo' in x for x in df1['col']]]

       col
0  foo abc
1   foobar
```

Instead of,

```
regex_pattern = r'foo(?!$)'
df1[df1['col'].str.contains(regex_pattern)]
```

Use [`re.compile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) (to cache your regex) + [`Pattern.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.search) inside a list comp,

```
p = re.compile(regex_pattern, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
df1[[bool(p.search(x)) for x in df1['col']]]

      col
1  foobar
```

If "col" has NaNs, then instead of

```
df1[df1['col'].str.contains(regex_pattern, na=False)]
```

Use,

```
def try_search(p, x):
    try:
        return bool(p.search(x))
    except TypeError:
        return False

p = re.compile(regex_pattern)
df1[[try_search(p, x) for x in df1['col']]]

      col
1  foobar
```

---

#### More Options for Partial String Matching: [`np.char.find`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.find.html#numpy.core.defchararray.find), [`np.vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html), [`DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html).

In addition to `str.contains` and list comprehensions, you can also use the following alternatives.

**`np.char.find`**
Supports substring searches (read: no regex) only.

```
df4[np.char.find(df4['col'].values.astype(str), 'foo') > -1]

          col
0     foo abc
1  foobar xyz
```

**`np.vectorize`**
This is a wrapper around a loop, but with lesser overhead than most pandas `str` methods.

```
f = np.vectorize(lambda haystack, needle: needle in haystack)
f(df1['col'], 'foo')
# array([ True,  True, False, False])

df1[f(df1['col'], 'foo')]

       col
0  foo abc
1   foobar
```

Regex solutions possible:

```
regex_pattern = r'foo(?!$)'
p = re.compile(regex_pattern)
f = np.vectorize(lambda x: pd.notna(x) and bool(p.search(x)))
df1[f(df1['col'])]

      col
1  foobar
```

**`DataFrame.query`**
Supports string methods through the python engine. This offers no visible performance benefits, but is nonetheless useful to know if you need to dynamically generate your queries.

```
df1.query('col.str.contains("foo")', engine='python')

      col
0     foo
1  foobar
```

More information on `query` and `eval` family of methods can be found at [Dynamically evaluate an expression from a formula in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779986/dynamic-expression-evaluation-in-pandas-using-pd-eval).

---

#### Recommended Usage Precedence

1. (First) `str.contains`, for its simplicity and ease handling NaNs and mixed data
2. List comprehensions, for its performance (especially if your data is purely strings)
3. `np.vectorize`
4. (Last) `df.query`

Comment: Could you edit in the correct method to use when searching for a string in two or more columns? Basically: `any(needle in haystack for needling in ['foo', 'bar'] and haystack in (df['col'], df['col2']))` and variations I tried all choke (it complains about `any()` and rightly so... But the doc is blissfully unclear as to how to do such a query.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy `df[['col1', 'col2']].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('foo|bar')).any(axis=1)`

Comment: @cs95 [Extracting rows with substring containing whitespace after + in pandas df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57238715/extracting-rows-with-substring-containing-whitespace-after-in-pandas-df) It was answered soon, but you might want to have a look at it.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii Looks like you missed the part of my answer where I mentioned regex metacharacters: "Sometimes, it is wise to escape your terms in case they have characters that can be interpreted as regex metacharacters".

Comment: @cs95 at that time, I  thought only of space as the problem and searched this page and documentation page for the same. While writing the question, special char came to my mind and I got quick answers before I could search for it. Great answer of yours! +1

Comment: Very helpful! Why do you need to insert `r` if regex = True by default? eg here: `df1[df1['col'].str.contains(r'foo(?!$)')]`

Comment: @00schneider r in this case is used to indicate a raw string literal. These make it easier to write regular expression strings. https://stackoverflow.com/q/2081640/

Comment: How to use this for finding values in multiple columns?

Comment: @MurtazaHaji you can .apply() any of these solutions across multiple columns. For more info on how to apply an operation column wise take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code

Comment: @MurtazaHaji Made an edit to my answer that shows you how to do that (it's in the "Basic Substring Search" section).

Comment: I tried the list comprehension, but in my case it was 6x slower than `str.contains(my_string, regex=False)`

Comment: @arno_v That's good to hear, looks like pandas performance is improving!

Comment: Extremely helpful !! Especially the 'import re' features are game changers. Chapeau!

Comment: Such a great answer - thank you!  For me the issue was not even realizing that the parens in my pattern were interpreted as a regex, and the warning didn't make that very clear. So I got the warning changed so it now says "**This pattern is interpreted as a regular expression, and has match groups. To actually get the groups, use str.extract.", See https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/44811

Comment: This answer has a lot of good information but it is hard to find.  Including the recommended code snippets for each case in the introduction would help. For example, including `str.contains('pattern',na=False)` in the intro would be helpful.  One of the two questions above this provides a different solution for ONLY this case -- so clearly this case is one of the most important to mention. I would be happy to do the edit if you like.

Comment: @JosiahYoder yes please I invite your edits as I am very inactive to do justice to post maintenance these days :(

Answer (score 67):

If anyone wonders how to perform a related problem: ***"Select column by partial string"***

Use:

```
df.filter(like='hello')  # select columns which contain the word hello
```

And to select rows by partial string matching, pass `axis=0` to filter:

```
# selects rows which contain the word hello in their index label
df.filter(like='hello', axis=0)
```

Comment: This can be distilled to: `df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('a')]`

Comment: which can be further distilled to `df.filter(like='a')`

Comment: this should be an own question + answer, already 50 people searched for it...

Comment: @PV8 question already exists: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31551412/how-to-select-dataframe-columns-based-on-partial-matching. But when I search on google for "pandas Select column by partial string", this thread appears first

Answer (score 29):

Quick note: if you want to do selection based on a partial string contained in the index, try the following:

```
df['stridx']=df.index
df[df['stridx'].str.contains("Hello|Britain")]
```

Comment: You can just df[df.index.to_series().str.contains('LLChit')]

Comment: to be even more concise, `to_series` is not needed: `df[df.index.str.contains('Hello|Britain')]`

Answer (score 24):

Should you need to do a *case insensitive* search for a string in a pandas dataframe column:

```
df[df['A'].str.contains("hello", case=False)]
```

Answer (score 23):

Say you have the following `DataFrame`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([['hello', 'hello world'], ['abcd', 'defg']], columns=['a','b'])
>>> df
       a            b
0  hello  hello world
1   abcd         defg
```

You can always use the `in` operator in a lambda expression to create your filter.

```
>>> df.apply(lambda x: x['a'] in x['b'], axis=1)
0     True
1    False
dtype: bool
```

The trick here is to use the `axis=1` option in the `apply` to pass elements to the lambda function row by row, as opposed to column by column.

Comment: How do I modify above to say that x['a'] exists only in beginning of x['b']?

Comment: apply is a bad idea here in terms of performance and memory. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code).

Answer (score 16):

You can try considering them as string as :

```
df[df['A'].astype(str).str.contains("Hello|Britain")]
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, your answer helped me a lot as I was struggling to filter a dataframe via a column where the data was of bool type. Your solution helped me do the filter I needed. +1 for you.

Answer (score 9):

Suppose we have a column named "ENTITY" in the dataframe `df`. We can filter our `df`,to have the entire dataframe `df`, wherein rows of "entity" column doesn't contain "DM" by using a mask as follows:

```
mask = df['ENTITY'].str.contains('DM')

df = df.loc[~(mask)].copy(deep=True)
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's what I ended up doing for partial string matches.  If anyone has a more efficient way of doing this please let me know.

```
def stringSearchColumn_DataFrame(df, colName, regex):
    newdf = DataFrame()
    for idx, record in df[colName].iteritems():

        if re.search(regex, record):
            newdf = concat([df[df[colName] == record], newdf], ignore_index=True)

    return newdf
```

Comment: Should be 2x to 3x faster if you compile regex before loop: regex = re.compile(regex) and then if regex.search(record)

Comment: @MarkokraM https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.compile says that the most recent regexs are cached for you, so you don't need to compile yourself.

Comment: Do not use iteritems to iterate over a DataFrame. It ranks last in terms of pandorability and performance

Comment: iterating over dataframes defeats the entire purpose of pandas. Use Garrett's solution instead

Answer (score 5):

Using contains didn't work well for my string with special characters. Find worked though.

```
df[df['A'].str.find("hello") != -1]
```

Answer (score 5):

A more generalised example - if looking for parts of a word OR specific words in a string:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([('cat andhat', 1000.0), ('hat', 2000000.0), ('the small dog', 1000.0), ('fog', 330000.0),('pet', 330000.0)], columns=['col1', 'col2'])
```

Specific parts of sentence or word:

```
searchfor = '.*cat.*hat.*|.*the.*dog.*'
```

Creat column showing the affected rows (can always filter out as necessary)

```
df["TrueFalse"]=df['col1'].str.contains(searchfor, regex=True)

    col1             col2           TrueFalse
0   cat andhat       1000.0         True
1   hat              2000000.0      False
2   the small dog    1000.0         True
3   fog              330000.0       False
4   pet 3            30000.0        False
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you want to search for some text in all columns of the Pandas dataframe, and not just in the subset of them. In this case, the following code will help.

```
df[df.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains('String To Find').any(), axis=1)]
```

Warning. This method is relatively slow, albeit convenient.

Answer (score 3):

Somewhat similar to @cs95's answer, but here you don't need to specify an engine:

```
df.query('A.str.contains("hello").values')
```

Answer (score 2):

There are answers before this which accomplish the asked feature, anyway I would like to show the most generally way:

```
df.filter(regex=".*STRING_YOU_LOOK_FOR.*")
```

This way let's you get the column you look for whatever the way is wrote.

( Obviusly, you have to write the proper regex expression for each case )

Comment: This filters on the column *headers*. It isn't general, it's incorrect.

Comment: @MicheldeRuiter that's still incorrect, that'd filter on index labels instead!

Answer (score 2):

My 2c worth:

I did the following:

```
sale_method = pd.DataFrame(model_data['Sale Method'].str.upper())
sale_method['sale_classification'] = \
    np.where(sale_method['Sale Method'].isin(['PRIVATE']),
             'private',
             np.where(sale_method['Sale Method']
                      .str.contains('AUCTION'),
                      'auction',
                      'other'
             )
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df[df['A'].str.contains("hello", case=False)]
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation to your code how it works and how it answers the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

### `query` API

As mentioned in other answers, you can use `query` to filter rows by making a call to `str.contains` inside the expression. A good thing about it is that unlike boolean indexing, you won't get the pesky `SettingWithCopyWarning` after using it. You can also pass the pattern defined locally (or elsewhere) using `@`. Also useful kwargs:

- `case=False`: performs case insensitive search
- `na=False`: fill in `False` for missing values e.g. NaN, NA, None etc.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['foo', 'foobar', 'bar', 'baZ', pd.NA]})
pat = r'f|z'
df.query('col.str.contains(@pat, case=False, na=False)')    # case-insensitive and return False if NaN

# or pass it as `local_dict`
df.query('col.str.contains(@pattern, case=False, na=False)', local_dict={'pattern': r'f|z'})
```

As shown above, you can handle NaN values in the column by passing `na=False`. This is less error-prone (and faster) than converting the column to `str` dtype or doing some other boolean checks as done in some answers on this page.

### Performance

Since Python string methods are not optimized, it's often faster to drop down to vanilla Python and perform whatever task you have using an explicit loop. So if you want good performance, use list comprehension rather than the vectorized `str.contains`. As you can see from the following benchmark (tested on Python 3.12.0 and pandas 2.1.1), `str.contains` while terse, is about 20% slower than a list comprehension (even with the ternary operator for NaN handling). Since `str.contains` is a loop implementation anyway, this gap exists for whatever size the DataFrame is.

```py
import re
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['foo', 'foobar', 'bar', 'baZ', pd.NA]*100000})
pat = re.compile(r'f|z', flags=re.I)

%timeit df[df['col'].str.contains(pat, na=False)]
# 375 ms ± 15.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit df[[bool(pat.search(x)) if (x==x) is True else False for x in df['col'].tolist()]]
# 318 ms ± 14 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```