# python - pandas select by partial string ValueError

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv that I'm loading into a dataframe. I only need the rows for which the `Organization` column contains a target string `affiliation`.

When I try to use `str.contains()` I get `ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values`.

I've looked at [Value Error when Slicing in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731714/value-error-when-slicing-in-pandas) and [pandas + dataframe - select by partial string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350770/pandas-dataframe-select-by-partial-string) and the following solution that both have works for me:

```
df = df[df['Organization'].str.contains(affiliation)==True]
```

or

```
df = df[df['Organization'].str.contains(affiliation).fillna(False)]
```

But, as a test, I did this:

```
print(len(df)) #99228
df = df[pd.notnull(df['Organization'])] #or df = df.dropna(subset=['Organization'])
print(len(df)) #99228
df = df[df['Organization'].str.contains(affiliation).fillna(False)]
print(len(df)) #1605
```

My question is: the `ValueError` I was getting without `==True` or `fillna(False)` attached to `str.contains()` seems to imply that the `Organization` column has `NaNs`. But then why do I get the same sized df after keeping only the non-null `Organization` rows? What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the content of your column `Organization`. It very likely contains strings and other data types. Therefore, `df['Organization'].str.contains(affiliation)` results in `NaN`for these values with other data types. You cannot use `NaN`for indexing but need to convert it into `False`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `str.contains('affiliation', na=False)`. [[docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)]

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: s = pd.Series(['foo','bar',np.nan,'this contains affiliation','baz',np.nan])

In [4]: s.str.contains('affiliation')
Out[4]:
0    False
1    False
2      NaN
3     True
4    False
5      NaN
dtype: object

In [5]: s.str.contains('affiliation', na=False)
Out[5]:
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool
```

Then you can index your DataFrame with that Boolean array.

Comment: Thanks but I knew I needed to do that. I didn't understand why it was happening if it wasn't because of NaNs