# Vectorized DataFrame Python-pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to figure out how to print a row given a known entry in a column within my data frame much like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350770/pandas-dataframe-select-by-partial-string) question. However, this wasn't working for my DataFrame.

```
In [10]: df
Out[10:
   A   B   C   D
0  a   b   c   d
1  t   f   h   e
2  j   r   y   k

In [11]: df[df['A'].str.contains('t')]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-618e00d5bb36> in <module>()
----> 1 df[df['A'].str.contains('t')]

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'str'
```

*Just to try and clarify my goal, say I know 't' is in my DataFrame somewhere and I also know it resides within column A, is there a search option that will print out the entire row it is located within?*

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: In what way does `df[df['A'].str.contains("t")]` (from that question) not work??

Comment: Comments on the deleted answer showed that this wasn't working since the OP was using an old version of pandas (0.8), and an upgrade (to 0.11) fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Vectorized string methods](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#basics-string-methods) were [introduced in pandas 0.9](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#v0-9-0-october-7-2012) (so it isn't available as a Series method in version you're using: 0.8). Refresh your pandas to the [latest stable version](http://pandas.pydata.org/getpandas.html) for the latest and greatest features.