# Search for "does-not-contain" on a DataFrame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, contains

I've done some searching and can't figure out how to filter a dataframe by

```
df["col"].str.contains(word)
```

however I'm wondering if there is a way to do the reverse: filter a dataframe by that set's compliment. eg: to the effect of

```
!(df["col"].str.contains(word))
```

Can this be done through a `DataFrame` method?

Answer (score 538, accepted):

You can use the invert (~) operator (which acts like a not for boolean data):

```
new_df = df[~df["col"].str.contains(word)]
```

where `new_df` is the copy returned by RHS.

*contains also accepts a regular expression...*

---

If the above throws a ValueError or TypeError, the reason is likely because you have mixed datatypes, so use `na=False`:

```
new_df = df[~df["col"].str.contains(word, na=False)]
```

Or,

```
new_df = df[df["col"].str.contains(word) == False]
```

Comment: Perfect! I'm SQL-familiar with regex and thought it was different in Python - saw a lot of articles with `re.complies` and told myself I'd get to that later. Looks like I overfit the search and it's just as you say : )

Comment: Maybe a full example would be helpful:
`df[~df.col.str.contains(word)]` returns a copy of the original dataframe with excluded rows matching the word.

Answer (score 93):

I was having trouble with the not (~) symbol as well, so here's another way from another [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350770/pandas-dataframe-select-by-partial-string):

```
df[df["col"].str.contains('this|that')==False]
```

Comment: Can it be combined like this? `df[df["col1"].str.contains('this'|'that')==False and df["col2"].str.contains('foo'|'bar')==True]`? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can. The syntax is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22086116/how-do-you-filter-pandas-dataframes-by-multiple-columns

Comment: Not to forget that if we want to rwmove rows which contain "|" we should use "\" like 
`df = df[~df["col"].str.contains('\|')]`

Answer (score 21):

You can use Apply and Lambda :

```
df[df["col"].apply(lambda x: word not in x)]
```

Or if you want to define more complex rule, you can use AND:

```
df[df["col"].apply(lambda x: word_1 not in x and word_2 not in x)]
```

Comment: I think 'in' works for checking equals so 'not in' will check not equals, will not check for not contains. right?

Comment: @RamanJoshi please read the question : Search for “does-not-contain”

Comment: I have read the question carefully, that's why I am saying to you that there is much difference in between "not equals" and "not contains". for eg. if we have list which containing items ["hello", "world", "test"] and if we want to check for "not equals" then text "ello" will return "true" as text is not equals to any of the items. but when we check for "not contains" it should return "false" as one item i.e. "Hello" contains the text "ello". I think you are getting the question wrong.

Comment: Hummm,  and my code is checking "does not contain" condition, not "equal" condition. What's the problem ? word_1 not in x means "x doesn't contain word_1" or in other word it means "word_1 is not found in x". It has nothing to do with being "equal" !!

Answer (score 20):

I hope the answers are already posted

I am adding the framework to find **multiple words and negate those from dataFrame**.

Here `'word1','word2','word3','word4'` = list of patterns to search

`df` = DataFrame

`column_a` = A column name from DataFrame df

```
values_to_remove = ['word1','word2','word3','word4'] 

pattern = '|'.join(values_to_remove)

result = df.loc[~df['column_a'].str.contains(pattern, case=False)]
```

Comment: this was the only method that worked for me

Answer (score 8):

I had to get rid of the NULL values before using the command recommended by Andy above. An example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index = [0, 1, 2], columns=['first', 'second', 'third'])
df.ix[:, 'first'] = 'myword'
df.ix[0, 'second'] = 'myword'
df.ix[2, 'second'] = 'myword'
df.ix[1, 'third'] = 'myword'
df

    first   second  third
0   myword  myword   NaN
1   myword  NaN      myword 
2   myword  myword   NaN
```

Now running the command:

```
~df["second"].str.contains(word)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'
```

I got rid of the NULL values using dropna() or fillna() first and retried the command with no problem.

Comment: You can also use `~df["second"].astype(str).str.contains(word)` to force conversion to `str`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43568760/pandas-drop-rows-where-column-contains

Comment: @Shoresh we can also use na = False as a solution of this problem

Answer (score 7):

To negate your query use `~`. Using [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) has the advantage of returning the valid observations of `df` directly:

```
df.query('~col.str.contains("word").values')
```

Comment: This is perfect when you want to chain operations
 (df
         .filter(items=['time', ' lat', ' long', ' col'])
         .rename(columns={' lat': 'lat', ' long': 'lng', ' col': 'col'})
         .query('lat != 0.0')
         .query('lng != 0.0')
         .query('~col.str.contains("word").values')
         )

Answer (score 3):

Additional to nanselm2's answer, you can use `0` instead of `False`:

```
df["col"].str.contains(word)==0
```

Comment: it looks like this also remove any rows with `NaN`

Answer (score 1):

somehow '.contains' didn't work for me but when I tried with '.isin' as mentioned by @kenan in the answer ([How to drop rows from pandas data frame that contains a particular string in a particular column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679930/how-to-drop-rows-from-pandas-data-frame-that-contains-a-particular-string-in-a-p)) it works. Adding further, if you want to look at the entire dataframe and remove those rows which has the specific word (or set of words) just use the loop below

```
for col in df.columns:
    df = df[~df[col].isin(['string or string list separeted by comma'])]
```

just remove ~ to get the dataframe that contains the word

Answer (score 0):

To compliment to the above question, if someone wants to remove all the rows with strings, one could do:

```
df_new=df[~df['col_name'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))]
```

Answer (score 0):

To add clarity to the top answer, the general pattern for filtering all columns that contain a specific word is:

```py
# Remove any column with "word" in the name
new_df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains("word")]

# Filter multiple words
new_df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains("word1|word2")]
```