# How do you filter pandas dataframes by multiple columns?

Tags: python, filter, pandas

To filter a DataFrame (df) by a single column, if we consider data with male and females we might:

```
males = df[df[Gender]=='Male']
```

Question 1: But what if the data spanned multiple years and I wanted to only see males for 2014?

In other languages I might do something like:

```
if A = "Male" and if B = "2014" then
```

(except I want to do this and get a subset of the original DataFrame in a new dataframe object)

Question 2: How do I do this in a loop, and create a dataframe object for each unique sets of year and gender (i.e. a df for: 2013-Male, 2013-Female, 2014-Male, and 2014-Female?

```
for y in year:

for g in gender:

df = .....
```

Comment: Do you want to *filter* it or *group* it?  If you want to create a separate DataFrame for each unique set of year and gender, look at `groupby`.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54358361/4909087) gives a comprehensive overview of boolean indexing and logical operators in pandas.

Answer (score 292, accepted):

Using `&` operator, don't forget to wrap the sub-statements with `()`:

```
males = df[(df[Gender]=='Male') & (df[Year]==2014)]
```

To store your DataFrames in a `dict` using a for loop:

```
from collections import defaultdict
dic={}
for g in ['male', 'female']:
    dic[g]=defaultdict(dict)
    for y in [2013, 2014]:
        dic[g][y]=df[(df[Gender]==g) & (df[Year]==y)] #store the DataFrames to a dict of dict
```

---

A demo for your `getDF`:

```
def getDF(dic, gender, year):
    return dic[gender][year]

print genDF(dic, 'male', 2014)
```

Comment: great answer zhangxaochen - could you edit your answer to show at the bottom how you might do a for loop, which creates the dataframes (with year and gender data) but adds them to a dictionary so they can be accessed later by my getDF method?

def GetDF(dict,key):
  return dict[key]

Comment: @yoshiserry what's the `key` like in your `getDF`? a single parameter or a tuple of keys? be specific plz ;)

Comment: hi it's a single key, just a word, that would correspond to the gender (male, or female) or year (13, 14)

Didn't know you could have a tuple of keys. Could you share an example of when and how you would do this?

Comment: could you have a look at this question too. I feel like you could answer it. Relates to pandas dataframes again.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22086619/how-to-apply-a-function-to-multiple-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe-at-one-time

Comment: is it possible to turn the gender dataframe column into a list to iterate over with a for loop?

Comment: @yoshiserry what? better to post your question in detail ;)

Comment: Note that the `Gender` and `Year` should both be strings, i.e., `'Gender'` and `'Year'`.

Answer (score 41):

Start from [pandas 0.13](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html), this is the most efficient way.

```
df.query('Gender=="Male" & Year=="2014" ')
```

Comment: Why should this be more efficient than the accepted answer?

Comment: @Bouncner just verify it against the high-voted answer.

Comment: This answer could be improved by showing the benchmark

Comment: This is not efficient. Using %timeit, `df.query(blah)` scored 1.81 ms ± 99.7 µs per loop (7 runs, 1000 loops each), whereas `df[(blah) & (blah)]` scored faster at 501 µs ± 15.3 µs per loop (7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Comment: Why not `Year==2014` instead of `Year=="2014"`?

Answer (score 37):

In case somebody wonders what is the faster way to filter (the accepted answer or the one from @redreamality):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

length = 100_000
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Year'] = np.random.randint(1950, 2019, size=length)
df['Gender'] = np.random.choice(['Male', 'Female'], length)

%timeit df.query('Gender=="Male" & Year=="2014" ')
%timeit df[(df['Gender']=='Male') & (df['Year']==2014)]
```

Results for 100,000 rows:

```
6.67 ms ± 557 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
5.54 ms ± 536 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Results for 10,000,000 rows:

```
326 ms ± 6.52 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
472 ms ± 25.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

So results depend on the size and the data. On my laptop, `query()` gets faster after 500k rows. Further, the string search in `Year=="2014"` has an unnecessary overhead (`Year==2014` is faster).

Comment: However, I think the `query` syntax is neater and close to SQL, which makes it nice for data since. The chery on the cake is that it's faster with many rows :)

Comment: Couldn't agree more, @csgroen.

Answer (score 29):

For more general boolean functions that you would like to use as a filter and that depend on more than one column, you can use:

```
df = df[df[['col_1','col_2']].apply(lambda x: f(*x), axis=1)]
```

where f is a function that is applied to every pair of elements (x1, x2) from col_1 and col_2 and returns True or False depending on any condition you want on (x1, x2).

Comment: A fleshed out example where you also define f would improve this answer.

Comment: Great idea! Use df[df[["col_1", "col_2"]].apply(lambda x: True if tuple(x.values) == ("val_1", "val_2") else False, axis=1)] to filter by a tuple of desired values for specific columns, for example. Or even shorter, df[df[["col_1", "col_2"]].apply(lambda x: tuple(x.values) == ("val_1", "val_2"), axis=1)]

Answer (score 8):

Since you are looking for a rows that basically meet a condition where Column_A='Value_A' and Column_B='Value_B'

you can do using `loc`

```
df = df.loc[df['Column_A'].eq('Value_A') & df['Column_B'].eq('Value_B')]
```

You can find full doc here [panda loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

Answer (score 6):

You can create your own filter function using `query` in `pandas`. Here you have filtering of `df` results by all the `kwargs` parameters. Dont' forgot to add some validators(`kwargs` filtering) to get filter function for your own `df`.

```
def filter(df, **kwargs):
    query_list = []
    for key in kwargs.keys():
        query_list.append(f'{key}=="{kwargs[key]}"')
    query = ' & '.join(query_list)
    return df.query(query)
```

Comment: Thanks for the elegant solution! I think it's the best out of all the rest. It combines the efficiency of using query with the versatility of having it as a function.

Comment: Note that this assumes the value `kwargs[key]` is a string; it can be made a bit more generic (at least ints and strings) by something like `val = kwargs[key]` and `val_str = f'"{val}"' if isinstance(val, str) else f'{str(val)}` and `query_list.append(f'{key}=={val_str}')`

Answer (score 2):

You can filter by multiple columns (more than two) by using the `np.logical_and` operator to replace `&` (or `np.logical_or` to replace `|`)

Here's an example function that does the job, if you provide target values for multiple fields. You can adapt it for different types of filtering and whatnot:

```
def filter_df(df, filter_values):
    """Filter df by matching targets for multiple columns.

    Args:
        df (pd.DataFrame): dataframe
        filter_values (None or dict): Dictionary of the form:
                `{<field>: <target_values_list>}`
            used to filter columns data.
    """
    import numpy as np
    if filter_values is None or not filter_values:
        return df
    return df[
        np.logical_and.reduce([
            df[column].isin(target_values) 
            for column, target_values in filter_values.items()
        ])
    ]
```

Usage:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'b': [1, 2, 3, 4]})

filter_df(df, {
    'a': [1, 2, 3],
    'b': [1, 2, 4]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

An improvement to Alex answer

```
def df_filter(df, **kwargs):
    query_list = []
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        if value is not None:
            query_list.append(f"{key}==@kwargs['{str(key)}']")
    query = ' & '.join(query_list)
    return df.query(query)
```

will remove None values so can be directly incoperated to functions with some values defaulting to None
also the previous one would not work if the value was not string , this will work on any type of arguments

Answer (score 0):

After a few years I came back to this question and can propose another solution, it's especially good when you have lots of filters included. We can create a several filtering masks and then operate on those filters:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'gender': ['Male', 'Female', 'Male'],
...                    'married': [True, False, False]})
>>> gender_mask = df['gender'] == 'Male'
>>> married_mask = df['married']
>>> filtered_df = df.loc[gender_mask & married_mask]
>>> filtered_df
  gender  married
0   Male     True
```

Maybe it's not the shortest solution, but it's readable and could be a great help to organize the code.

Answer (score 0):

My dataframe has 25 columns and I want to leave for future a freedom to choice any kind of filters (num of params, conditions).
I use this:

```
    
def flex_query(params):
    res = load_dataframe()
    if type(params) is not list:
        return None
    for el in params:
        res = res.query(f"{el[0]} {el[1]} {el[2]}")
    return res
```

And calling this:

```
res = flex_query([['DATE','==', '"2022-09-26"'],['LEVEL','>=',2], ['PERCENT','>',10.2]])
```

Where 'DATE', 'LEVEL', 'PERCENT' - column names.
As you can see, here are very flexible query method with several params and different type of conditions. This method gives me possibility to compare int, float, string - 'all in one'

Answer (score 0):

Another more generalised solution I found is using the [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) method on the data frame.

Example:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'A': [1, 2, 1, 1],
        'B': [5, 6, 7, 8],
        'C': [9, 10, 11, 10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df[['A', 'C']].where(lambda row: row.values == [1, 10]).dropna()
# >> 
#    A      C
# 3  1.0    10.0
```

`dropna()` makes sure only rows that have a full match are returned.
Also, make sure the values you're checking for are in the correct order. In this example, `1` is for the `A` column and `10` is for the `C` column values