# How to fllter a pandas DataFrame by multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to subset a pandas DataFrame in python based on two logical statements

i.e.

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df[df.col1 = 1 and df.col2 = 3]
```

but I'm getting invalid syntax on line3.

Is there a way to do this in one line?

Comment: You confused assignment `=` and comparison `==`.

Comment: This question is duplicated. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22086116/how-do-you-filter-pandas-dataframes-by-multiple-columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use logical operators. `==` is equals for returning boolean, `=` is setting a value.

Try:

```
df[(df.col1 == 1) & (df.col2 == 3)]
```

Comment: You need to add `()` around each expression, or this has the same error. Note also the use of the bitwise `&` vs. the logical `and` operator.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** as mentioned by @jp_data_analysis and [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy), the following solution is not the best one given it uses chained indexing. Please refer to Matt W. and AChampion solution.

An alternative one line solution.

```
>>> d = {'col1': [1, 2, 1], 'col2': [3, 4, 2]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

>>> df[df.col1==1][df.col2==3]

   col1  col2
0     1     3
```

I have added a third row, with `'col1'=1` and `'col2'=2`, so we can have an extra negative test case.

Comment: downvoted - chained indexing is widely discouraged, see [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) for an explanation why.

Comment: You are right @jp_data_analysis. I have added this information to the original answer.