# Filter on specific values in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, transpose

I am trying to filter on certain values in many columns
in Column (Dimension) filter on Education, then in next column (indicator name), filter on Mean years of schooling (years), then in Country Name Column filter on USA, Canada,.....etc

I have tried the below script but I couldn't filter on the specifics mentioned above

```
raw_data={}
for Dimension in new_df["Dimension"]:
    dimension_df=new_df.loc[new_df["Dimension"]==Dimension]
    arr=[]
    arr.append(dimension_df["Indicator Name"].values[0])
    arr.append(dimension_df["ISO Country Code"].values[0])
    raw_data[Dimension]=arr

pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
```

Comment: please show an example of yours input and output dataframe

Comment: Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22086116/how-do-you-filter-pandas-dataframes-by-multiple-columns?