# Filter dataframe based on 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I have a big dataframe

| city | Flow |
| --- | --- |
| Berlin | False |
| Berlin | True |
| Vienna | False |
| Vienna | True |
| Vienna | False |
| Frankfurt | True |
| Frankfurt | False |

I want to remove only the rows where city and flow is Vienna and false using python

Resulting dataframe should be

| city | Flow |
| --- | --- |
| Berlin | False |
| Berlin | True |
| Vienna | True |
| Frankfurt | True |
| Frankfurt | False |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do you filter pandas dataframes by multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22086116/how-do-you-filter-pandas-dataframes-by-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
>>> df[df["city"].ne("Vienna")|df["Flow"]]
        city   Flow
0     Berlin  False
1     Berlin   True
3     Vienna   True
5  Frankfurt   True
6  Frankfurt  False
```

Comment: Do you know how to perform this filter if flow was not a boolean

Comment: `df[df["city"].ne("Vienna")|df["Flow"].ne("False")]`