# How to drop rows from pandas data frame that contains a particular string in a particular column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large data frame in python and I want to drop all rows that have a particular string inside a particular column.

For example, I want to drop all rows which have the string "XYZ" as a substring in the column C of the data frame.

Can this be implemented in an efficient way using .drop() method?

Answer (score 304, accepted):

pandas has vectorized string operations, so you can just filter out the rows that contain the string you don't want:

```
In [91]: df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[5,3,5,6], C=["foo","bar","fooXYZbar", "bat"]))

In [92]: df
Out[92]:
   A          C
0  5        foo
1  3        bar
2  5  fooXYZbar
3  6        bat

In [93]: df[~df.C.str.contains("XYZ")]
Out[93]:
   A    C
0  5  foo
1  3  bar
3  6  bat
```

Comment: Although what you wrote is correct and more readable, a shorter method would be :`df[~df.C.str.contains("XYZ")]`

Comment: When I do this it works perfectly, however it also does not show any rows in which the value was NaN. Is there a way to get those back so that the resulting data frame contains rows that do not contain the desired string and also NaN?

Comment: how would you do this if instead of "XYZ" you wanted to see if it contained anything inside of a large list of maybe a 1000 different things to look for.

Comment: let's assume my column name is saved in a list in first position, i.e. columns_names[0] . How do I change the command? I tryed df[~df.columns_names[0].str.contains("XYZ")] but it does not work

Comment: What if the name of the column has a space in it?

Comment: I get an error: `TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'`, any ideas regarding this issue?

Comment: The problem solved by adding `na=False`

Comment: When I use '.' as symbol to drop, it drops the entire dataframe. How would you do it if you want to drop rows where a column includes a point?

Comment: To remove rows which contains partial string, you can use str.contains(r'XYZ(?!$)')

Answer (score 152):

If your string constraint is not just one string you can drop those corresponding rows with:

```
df = df[~df['your column'].isin(['list of strings'])]
```

The above will drop all rows containing elements of your list

Comment: How would you do the inverse of this? I want to check if the column value contains any of the strings. pseudo: `for string in list_of_strings, check if column contains it`

Comment: Just remove the "~"
df = df[df['your column'].isin(['list of strings'])]

Comment: Already got that going, but thanks

Comment: What if we don't know the column?

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare if you know the column index you can always pass in df[df.columns[i]] where I is the column index

Comment: How would you drop from multiple columns instead of just one?

Comment: That's very tricky because the rows won't be the same for all columns, you can try `df[['list of cols']].isin([...])`

Comment: This worked for me but I realized that 'list of strings' should be the exact string you want to remove

Comment: I don't know the reason, but does not work. No error message, gives back df without changes.

Comment: for multiple columns (to check in the entire dataframe) I used a simple for loop like..........  `for col in df.columns: df = df[~df[col].isin(['string or string list separeted by comma'])]`

Answer (score 55):

This will only work if you want to compare exact strings.
It will not work in case you want to check if the column string contains any of the strings in the list.

The right way to compare with a list would be :

```
searchfor = ['john', 'doe']
df = df[~df.col.str.contains('|'.join(searchfor))]
```

Answer (score 28):

Slight modification to the code. Having *na=False* will skip empty values. Otherwise you can get an error *TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: float*

```
df[~df.C.str.contains("XYZ", na=False)]
```

Source: [TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52297740/typeerror-bad-operand-type-for-unary-float)

Answer (score 16):

```
new_df = df[df.C != 'XYZ']
```

Reference: https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_dropping_column_and_rows/

Answer (score 10):

The below code will give you list of all the rows:-

```
df[df['C'] != 'XYZ']
```

To store the values from the above code into a dataframe :-

```
newdf = df[df['C'] != 'XYZ']
```

Comment: This Syntax is way more easier to remember. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

if you do not want to delete all NaN, use

```
df[~df.C.str.contains("XYZ") == True]
```