# Dropping rows with specific string value Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame of apple stock data and Close column has a few "null" strings in it. I cannot plot my data because I keep getting 'Cannot convert string to...' error. When I try the code below I get an error '**AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'close_arr'**. This code was based on the answer provided in this thread [How to drop rows from pandas data frame that contains a particular string in a particular column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679930/how-to-drop-rows-from-pandas-data-frame-that-contains-a-particular-string-in-a-p)

```
apl = pd.read_csv(path, index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)
close_arr = aapl['Close']
aapl = aapl[~aapl.close_arr.str.contains("null")]
aapl.head()
```

Here is the info()

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 9234 entries, 1980-12-12 to 2017-07-26
Data columns (total 6 columns):
Adj Close    9234 non-null object
Close        9234 non-null object
High         9234 non-null object
Low          9234 non-null object
Open         9234 non-null object
Volume       9234 non-null object
dtypes: object(6)
memory usage: 505.0+ KB
```

I have also tried:

```
aapl = aapl[~aapl['Close'].str.contains("null")]
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Provide us with an example of your code by e.g. apl.head().to_dict()

Comment: My code is included in the question.

Comment: @user3088202 Your df.head() would help.

Comment: @user3088202 code was the wrong word used. I meant a sample of your data, e.g. apl.head().to_dict(). When you provide this we can help you quicker and time is not wasted. I don't want to sound very harsh but please look at this link for future posts: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `df.replace` followed by `df.dropna`:

```
aapl = aapl.replace('null', np.nan).dropna()
```

Comment: Looks like there still in there because when I try to plt.plot(aapl) I get ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'null'

Comment: @user3088202 You did assign it right? It is not inplace.

Comment: @user3088202 Look at my next solution.

Comment: @user3088202 Good to hear :) Please consider upvoting/accepting when you can :)

Comment: will do, absolutely.