# How to Remove Rows from Pandas Data Frame that Contains any String in a Particular Column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, machine-learning

I have CSV data in the following format:

```
+-------------+-------------+-------+
|  Location   | Num of Reps | Sales |
+-------------+-------------+-------+
| 75894       |           3 |    12 |
| Burkbank    |           2 |    19 |
| 75286       |           7 |    24 |
| Carson City |           4 |    13 |
| 27659       |           3 |    17 |
+-------------+-------------+-------+
```

The `Location` column is of the `object` datatype. What I would like to do is to remove all rows that have non-numeric Location labels. So my desired output, given the above table would be:

```
+----------+-------------+-------+
| Location | Num of Reps | Sales |
+----------+-------------+-------+
|    75894 |           3 |    12 |
|    75286 |           7 |    24 |
|    27659 |           3 |    17 |
+----------+-------------+-------+
```

Now, I could hard code the solution in the following manner:

```
list1 = ['Carson City ', 'Burbank'];
df = df[~df['Location'].isin(['list1'])]
```

Which was inspired by the following post:

[How to drop rows from pandas data frame that contains a particular string in a particular column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679930/how-to-drop-rows-from-pandas-data-frame-that-contains-a-particular-string-in-a-p#comment76554441_43399866)

However, what I am looking for is a general solution, that will work for any table of the type outlined above.

Answer (score 5):

Or you could do

```
df[df['Location'].str.isnumeric()]
```

```
  Location  Num of Reps  Sales
0    75894            3     12
2    75286            7     24
4    27659            3     17
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pd.to_numeric` to *coerce* non numeric values to `nan` and then filter based on if the *Location* is `nan`:

```
df[pd.to_numeric(df.Location, errors='coerce').notnull()]

#Location  Num of Reps  Sales
#0  75894            3     12
#2  75286            7     24
#4  27659            3     17
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [139]: df[~df.Location.str.contains('\D')]
Out[139]:
  Location  Num of Reps  Sales
0    75894            3     12
2    75286            7     24
4    27659            3     17
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df[df['Location'].str.isdigit()]


  Location  Num of Reps  Sales
0    75894            3     12
2    75286            7     24
4    27659            3     17
```