# How to implement a "not" filter on a pandas series (as opposed to a dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas

The constructs to work with include:

**Filter with `like` or `regex` or `in`:**

```
 series.filter(like='some pattern')

 series.filter(regex='some regex')
```

But those are *positive* not ***negative*** filters..

On a `Dataframe` we can do a `not` with a **`tilde`** as follows:

```
  df.filter(~('some pattern' in df['some_column']))
```

But that is not available on a `Series`.   So what is the `not` filter on  a `Series`?

Comment: Do you want to filter out columns or rows? `filter` gets you columns, so your syntax seems wrong.

Comment: It looks like you could just do `df[~df['some_column'].str.contains(pattern)]` if you're trying to filter rows. Same for `df.columns`, just use `df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains(pattern)]` for filtering on columns.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ  Your syntax seems to be for `dataframe` not `Series` : the latter do no include column specifiers

Comment: Sorry about that, I misread. However, my first suggestion to filter on rows applies. `series[~series.str.contains(pattern)]`

Comment: what is the `series.str` ?

Comment: It's the accessor you use to run vectorised string functions on the series/dataframe columns.

Comment: sorry,  my code had become messy : now cleaned up it is back to a series -and your suggestion about `~series.str.contains` works well. please make it an answer

Comment: btw are there other important objects in `Series` similar to `str` : i.e that permit accessing additional methods?  For example `series.int` ?

Comment: No, that's alright. I think your question is a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28679930/4909087 You can delete or self-mark.

Comment: Well, there is the `.dt` for dates and `.cat` for categorical columns. Other types do not have an accessor.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ  mine is not a duplicate because it is about a *series* (i had already seen the dataframe questions..): and your answer is in fact also *new* material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiomatic method for filtering series is to use `str.contains` and negate the result.

```
series = series[~series.str.contains(pattern)]
```

If your pattern is not regex (but rather a simple substring pattern), I'd suggest a list comprehension as a faster alternative:

```
series = pd.Series([pattern not in v for v in series])
```

---

```
s = pd.Series(['ABC123', 'ABCdef', 'hijk'])

s[~s.str.contains('ABC')] 
2    hijk
dtype: object
```

Comment: I'd like to point out this answer brings up an important (and previously unfamiliar to me) attribute **`.str`** of a `Series` - and which distinguishes it from a `DataFrame`

Comment: @javadba Yup, also if you were to perform this operation on a dataframe column, you would still need the `.str` accessor since dataframe columns are nothing but Series :)