# Deleting data in pandas given a string condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am having trouble understanding the mechanics here given the following.

I have a `dataframe` reading from a `.csv` :

```
  a1 b1 c1
1 aa bb cc
2 ab ba ca 

df.drop(df['a1'].str.contains('aa',case = False))
```

I want to drop all the rows in column a1 that contain 'aa'

I believe to have attempted everything on here but still get the :

> ValueError: labels [False False False ... False False False] not contained in axis

Yes, I have also tried

```
skipinitialspace=True
axis=1
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `df[~df.a1.str.contains('aa')]
`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`str.contains` returns a mask:

```
df['a1'].str.contains('aa',case = False)

1     True
2    False
Name: a1, dtype: bool
```

However, `drop` accepts index labels, not boolean masks. If you open up the help on `drop`, you may observe this first-hand:

> ```
> ?df.drop
>
> Signature: df.drop(labels=None, axis=0, index=None, columns=None, level=None, inplace=False, errors='raise')
> Docstring:
> Return new object with labels in requested axis removed.
>
> Parameters
> ----------
> labels : single label or list-like
>     Index or column labels to drop.
> ```

You could figure out the index labels from the mask and pass *those* to drop

```
idx = df.index[df['a1'].str.contains('aa')]
df.drop(idx)

   a1  b1  c1
2  ab  ba  ca
```

However, this is too windy, so I'd recommend just sticking to the pandaic method of dropping rows based on conditions, *boolean indexing*:

```
df[~df['a1'].str.contains('aa')]

   a1  b1  c1
2  ab  ba  ca
```

If anyone is interested in removing rows that contain strings in a list

```
df = df[~df['a1'].str.contains('|'.join(my_list))]
```

Make sure to strip white spaces. Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/45681254/9500464

Comment: A trivial speed improvement, if applicable, is to set `regex=False`.

Comment: So you're recommending to drop the mask, basically :-)

Comment: Thank you for this! I am still so confused I really need to review this in depth.

Comment: @g_altobelli it's pretty straightforward, it needs to know the index labels, because it will remove those. It doesn't accept a boolean mask because it doesn't _need_ to accept one (there's enough indexers that do that already, `__getitem__` and `loc` are two of them).

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I just got it thank you!!! This makes so much more sense now. I am not sure why I made this so complicated for myself.