# How to delete substrings with specific characters in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
COL

hi A/P_90890 how A/P_True A/P_/93290 are AP_wueiwo A/P_|iwoeu you A/P_?9028k ?
...
 Im  fine, what A/P_49 A/P_0.0309 about you?
```

The expected result should be:

```
COL

hi how are you?
...
Im fine, what about you?
```

How can I remove efficiently from a column and for the full pandas dataframe all the strings that have `A/P_`?

I tried with this regular expression:

```
A/P_(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+
```

However, I do not know if there's a more simpler or robust way of removing all those substrings from my dataframe. How can I remove all the strings that have `A/P_` at the beginning?

**UPDATE**

I tried:

```
df_sess['COL'] = df_sess['COL'].str.replace(r'A/P(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', '')
```

And it works, however I would like to know if there's a more robust way of doing this. Possibily with a regular expression.

Comment: You want to remove `A/P_1` and keep the rest of the string yes?

Comment: No, I want to remove the full string... in other words I want to remove all the strings that have `A/P_`, and let there the clean ones @Abhishek

Comment: so you want to delete the entire row where any column has `A/P_`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to drop rows from pandas data frame that contains a particular string in a particular column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679930/how-to-drop-rows-from-pandas-data-frame-that-contains-a-particular-string-in-a-p)

Comment: post a testable dataframe (with a few columns and rows) and expected result

Comment: No because I dont want to drop rows, I want to drop the tokens @abishek

Comment: I updated the question @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: @anon, `hi how are you?` --> there's no `are` word in your input value

Comment: I updated the table @RomanPerekhrest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one way could be to use `\S*` matching all non withespaces after `A/P_` and also add `\s` to remove the whitespace after the string to remove, such as:

```
df_sess['COL'] = df_sess['col'].str.replace(r'A/P_\S*\s', '')
```

In you input, it seems there is an typo error (or at least I think so), so with this input:

```
df_sess = pd.DataFrame({'col':['hi A/P_90890 how A/P_True A/P_/93290 are A/P_wueiwo A/P_|iwoeu you A/P_?9028k ?',
                              'Im fine, what A/P_49 A/P_0.0309 about you?']})
print (df_sess['col'].str.replace(r'A/P_\S*\s', ''))
0            hi how are you ?
1    Im fine, what about you?
Name: col, dtype: object
```

you get the expected output

Comment: I am still having a large sequence of spaces, any idea of how to delete them into a single space?

Comment: @anon you can `.str.replace(r'\s+', ' ')` after the `replace(r'A/P_\S*\s', '')` to select all the sequence composed of 1 whitespace or more (`'\s+`) and replace it by one whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
(df['COL'].replace('A[/P|P][^ ]+', '', regex=True)
          .replace('\s+',' ', regex=True))
```

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'COL': 
    ["hi A/P_90890 how A/P_True A/P_/93290 AP_wueiwo A/P_|iwoeu you A/P_?9028k ?",
    "Im  fine, what A/P_49 A/P_0.0309 about you?"]
})

df['COL'] = (df['COL'].replace('A[/P|P][^ ]+', '', regex=True)
                      .replace('\s+',' ', regex=True))
```

Returns (oh, there is an extra space before ?):

```
                        COL
0              hi how you ?
1  Im fine, what about you?
```

Answer (score 2):

Because of pandas 0.23.0 bug in `replace()` function (https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21159) when trying to replace by regex pattern the error occurs:

```
df.COL.str.replace(regex_pat, '', regex=True)
...
--->
TypeError: Type aliases cannot be used with isinstance().
```

I would suggest to use `pandas.Series.apply` function with precompiled regex pattern:

```
In [1170]: df4 = pd.DataFrame({'COL': ['hi A/P_90890 how A/P_True A/P_/93290 are AP_wueiwo A/P_|iwoeu you A/P_?9028k ?', 'Im  fine, what A/P_49 A/P_0.0309 about you?']})

In [1171]: pat = re.compile(r'\s*A/?P_[^\s]*')

In [1172]: df4['COL']= df4.COL.apply(lambda x: pat.sub('', x))

In [1173]: df4
Out[1173]: 
                         COL
0           hi how are you ?
1  Im  fine, what about you?
```