# Pandas How to delete rows containing required string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to delete all rows containing required string ,

Suppose I have following dataframe:

```
A    B    C
1    a    x
w    g    n
3    l    p
j    p    v
```

I want to delete all rows containing string `p`. I have search for it but most of the answer is on the basis of column name , in my case I will not be aware of column it can be present in any of the column.

Output dataframe should be

```
A    B    C
1    a    x
w    g    n
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to drop rows from pandas data frame that contains a particular string in a particular column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679930/how-to-drop-rows-from-pandas-data-frame-that-contains-a-particular-string-in-a-p)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For filtering strings:

```
df = df[(df != 'p').all(axis=1)]
```

Compare for not equal:

```
print ((df != 'p'))
      A      B      C
0  True   True   True
1  True   True   True
2  True   True  False
3  True  False   True
```

And test for all `True`s per row:

```
print ((df != 'p').all(axis=1))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Or:

```
df = df[~(df == 'p').any(axis=1)]
```

Test for equal:

```
print ((df == 'p'))
       A      B      C
0  False  False  False
1  False  False  False
2  False  False   True
3  False   True  False
```

Test at least one `True` per row:

```
print ((df == 'p').any(axis=1))
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
dtype: bool
```

Invert boolean mask:

```
print (~(df == 'p').any(axis=1))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

For filtering substrings use [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with `apply`:

```
df = df[~df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.contains('p')).any(axis=1)]
```

Or:

```
df = df[~df.stack().astype(str).str.contains('p').unstack().any(axis=1)]
```

---

```
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  1  a  x
1  w  g  n
```

Comment: Ca I pass list of values to it? Or need to do using for loop only.

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare - Yes, then use `df = df[~(df.isin(['p','a'])).any(1)]`

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare - And for subtrings `df = df[~df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.contains('p|a')).any(axis=1)]`

Comment: Thanks brother !!