# Pandas - Adding dummy header column in csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, header

I am trying concat several csv files by customer group using the below code:

```
files = glob.glob(file_from + "/*.csv") <<-- Path where the csv resides
df_v0 = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in files]) <<-- Dataframe that concat all csv files from files mentioned above
```

The problem is the number of column in the csv varies by customer and they do not have a header file.

I am trying to see if I could add in a dummmy header column with labels such as col_1, col_2 ...  depending on the number of columns in that csv.

Could anyone guide as to how could I get this done. Thanks.

Update on trying to search for a specific string in the Dataframe:

**Sample Dataframe**

```
col_1,col_2,col_3
fruit,grape,green
fruit,watermelon,red
fruit,orange,orange
fruit,apple,red
```

Trying to filter out rows having the word red and expect it to return rows 2 and 4.

Tried the below code:

```
df[~df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.contains('red')).any(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameters `header=None` for default range columns `0, 1, 2` and `skiprows=1` if necessary remove original columns names:

```
df_v0 = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, header=None, skiprows=1) for f in files])
```

If want also change columns names add `rename`:

```
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f, header=None, skiprows=1).rename(columns = lambda x: f'col_{x + 1}') 
        for f in files]
df_v0 = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: one more help. files is a list that has list of filenames stored in it. I have an issue where few filename are written in upper case (eg : FILE1.CSV) and few are in small case (eg: file2.csv).. How could we make them all small case. Could you please assist on that. Thanks..

Comment: @darkhorse - not sure if understand, `files` return list of filenames with upper and lower names. Then looping by them and DataFrame are created. If change filenames to lowercase then errors will raise - file not exist. But if realluy need it use `pd.read_csv(f.lower(), ...`

Comment: if I got that right, are filenames case - sensitive when read in pandas. For example if file name is FILE1.CSV and if I pass in file1.csv will it fail because they are case-sensitive.

Comment: got another question. I am trying to search for a specific text from the  entire dataframe (df_v0). Need to scan through all rows and columns. I am able to filter by a specific column but not sure how to extend this to the entire Dataframe..

Comment: @darkhorse - do you think substring or not?

Comment: Basically I am trying to search for a string / integer and if any rows have that value trying to filer it out to a new Dataframe.. Hope this makes sense..

Comment: @darkhorse - I think need [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51168105/2901002)

Comment: tried the reference shared but dint work. I have updated the initial message with a sample dataframe and the code I tried.. Could you please assist.

Comment: @darkhorse - You are really close, only remove `~` like `df[df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.contains('red')).any(axis=1)]`

Comment: Thank you for that.