# Removing rows of duplicate headers or strings same columns and blank lines in pandas in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, spyder

I have a sample **[data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yd82getbcs9cpri/Data_sample_truncated.txt?dl=0)** (`Data_sample_truncated.txt`) which I truncated from a big data. It has 3 fields - `"Index", "Time" and "RxIn.Density[**x**, ::]"` Here I used x as integer as `x` can vary for any range. In this data it is `0-15`. The combination of the 3 column fields is unique. For different `"Index"` field the `"Time" and "RxIn.Density[**x**, ::]"` can be same or different. For each new `"Index"` value the data has a `blank line` and almost similar column headers except for `"RxIn.Density[**x**, ::]"` where `x` is increasing when new `"Index"` value is reached. The data which I export from `ADS` (circuit simulation software) gives me like this format while exporting.

Now I want to format the data so that all the data are merged together under 3 unique column fields - `"Index", "Time" and "RxIn.Density"`. You can see I want to remove the strings `[**x**, ::]` in the new dataframe of the 3rd column. Here is the **[sample final data file that I want](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4jnttn921iyrw04/Data-format_I_want_after_formatting.txt?dl=0)** after formatting (`Data-format_I_want_after_formatting.txt`). So I want the following -

- The blank lines (or rows) to be removed
- All the other header lines to be removed keeping the top header only and changing the 3rd column header to `"RxIn.Density"`
- Keeping all the data merged under the unique column fields - `"Index", "Time" and "RxIn.Density"`, even if the data values are duplicate.

My MATLAB code is in the below:

```
import pandas as pd

#create DataFrame from csv with columns f and v 
df = pd.read_csv('Data_sample_truncated.txt', sep="\s+", names=['index','time','v'])

#boolean mask for identify columns of new df   
m = df['v'].str.contains('RxIn')

#new column by replace NaNs by forward filling
df['g'] = df['v'].where(m).ffill()

#get original ordering for new columns
#cols = df['g'].unique()

#remove rows with same values in v and g columns
#df = df[df['v'] != df['g']]

df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['index', 'time'], keep=False)

df.to_csv('target.txt', index=False, sep='\t')
```

The generated `target.txt` file is not what I wanted. You can check it **[here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x0qdobrpyuewyb9/target.txt?dl=0)**. Can anyone help what is wrong with my code and what to do to fix it so that I wan my intended formatting?

I am using Spyder 3.2.6 (Anaconda) where python 3.6.4 64-bit is embedded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just filter out rows, that you do not want(check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679930/how-to-drop-rows-from-pandas-data-frame-that-contains-a-particular-string-in-a-p)):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Data_sample_truncated.txt', sep="\s+")
df.columns = ["index","time","RxIn.Density","1"]
del df["1"]
df = df[~df["RxIn.Density"].str.contains("Rx")].reset_index(drop=True)
df.to_csv('target.txt', index=False, sep='\t')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Data_sample_truncated.txt', sep='\s+', names=['index', 'time', 'RxIn.Density', 'mask'], header=None)

df = df[df['mask'].isna()].drop(['mask'], axis=1)

df.to_csv('target.txt', index=False, sep='\t')
```