# TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: float

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = df[~df["column"].str.contains("Total")]

TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'
```

Why does `.str.contains()` return a float? What should I be doing here?

Comment: what is the out put for df["column"].dtypes

Comment: @kindall Oh so it's just operator precedence? I'll try `df[~(df["column"].str.contains("Total"))]`

Comment: After some testing that doesn't seem to be the case, sorry for the red herring.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

I think there are `NaN`s values, so need specify parameter `na`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'column': ['Total','a',np.nan],
    'B': list(range(3))
})
print (df)
  column  B
0  Total  0
1      a  1
2    NaN  2

df = df[~df["column"].str.contains("Total", na=False)]
print (df)
  column  B
1      a  1
2    NaN  2
```

Comment: I have the same error, and I'm basically using .contains on a specific column of my df. I chcked it, and it does not have any NaN's. I added the na=False, and the error disappears. How could I explain the error I get, even though the column I am working with is a string with no NaNs? So I am using this line: 
df_main = df_main[~df_main['Category'].str.contains('|'.join(searchfor))], where searchfor is a list of words. Doing this generates the error

Comment: Okay, so I solved my problem. It was a faulty source of my csv file. I hadn't cleared all cells, so pandas was taking some of them as NaN.

Answer (score 3):

In this type, we will see that we have some column values that are nan or empty so we were not able to do this. Hence, when you applied the code as here given below it, will work.

```
df_pcc_mod = df_pcc_mod[~df_pcc_mod['Invoice'].str.contains('Reversed',na=False)]
```

Comment: TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'