# Deleting/dropping rows in pandas DataFrame with particular string in ANY column

Tags: python, pandas

May be a simply answer so apologies in advance (minimal coding experience).

I am trying to drop any rows with particular string (Economy 7) from ANY column and have been trying to go off this thread:

[How to drop rows from pandas data frame that contains a particular string in a particular column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679930/how-to-drop-rows-from-pandas-data-frame-that-contains-a-particular-string-in-a-p)

Couldn't get it to work but tried this code on a previous DataFrame (now df = energy) and it seemed to work although now it comes up with an error:

```
no_eco = energy[~energy.apply(lambda series: series.str.contains('Economy 7')).any(axis=1)]
```

`AttributeError: ('Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas', 'occurred at index existingProductCodeGas')`

Any suggestions? ps DataFrame is extremely large.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select only object columns, obviously strings by [`select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
df = energy.select_dtypes(object)
#added regex=False for improve performance like mentioned @jpp, thank you
mask = ~df.apply(lambda series: series.str.contains('Economy 7', regex=False)).any(axis=1)
no_eco = energy[mask]
```

**Sample**:

```
energy = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('adabbb')
})

print (energy)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  a  4  7  1  5  a
1  b  5  8  3  3  d
2  c  4  9  5  6  a
3  d  5  4  7  9  b
4  e  5  2  1  2  b
5  f  4  3  0  4  b

df = energy.select_dtypes(object)
mask = ~df.apply(lambda series: series.str.contains('d')).any(axis=1)
no_eco = energy[mask]
print (no_eco)

   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  a  4  7  1  5  a
2  c  4  9  5  6  a
4  e  5  2  1  2  b
5  f  4  3  0  4  b
```

Comment: Seems to have the same about of observations in new variable no_eco so doesn't seem to have dropped anything. Also if whole DataFrame is converted to string would integers and floats be converted too? @jezrael

Comment: Still the same amount of observations in new variable @jezrael

Comment: @GerardChurch - Added sample data, if solution with your real data not working, add [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: code still creating variable which has same amount of observation and now no columns. Example code is in the original post?

Comment: @GerardChurch - hmmm, my sample data remove all rows with `d`, if solution not woring with `Economy 7` it seems no match - no value `Economy 7` in data. Can you test some another string?

Comment: yes not sure why it is not working. Just tried it with another string 'Standard' but hasn't taken any rows out either.

Comment: @GerardChurch - Without your data hard to know. Are data confidental?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. Thanks for trying anyway, much appreciated.

Comment: This code seems to have worked this morning and has dropped all 'Economy 7' rows. Must have been having a moment yesterday. Many thanks.

Comment: code seems to have had a wobbly and now gives following error: `KeyError: "['nan' 'nan' 'nan' ... 'nan' 'nan' 'nan'] not found in axis"` Do you know why this might be as I haven't changed anything.

Comment: @geds133 - What return `mask` ? Maybe need `mask = ~df.apply(lambda series: series.str.contains('Economy 7', regex=False, na=False)).any(axis=1)`

Comment: Yeah returns the last line. Code still doesn't seem to work, looks as if it is searching for nan as column headers? @jezrael

Comment: @geds133 - it return last line? It has to return `True` and `False` values in Series.

Comment: Apologies it works when I stop running code beneath so must have affected it somewhere below somehow. Sorry about the false alarm.

Answer (score 0):

We can drop rows if any of the column contains a particular string, using to_string method

```
df.drop(df[df.apply(lambda row: 'Tony' in row.to_string(header=False), axis=1)].index, inplace=True)
```

complete example is

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Name', 'Location'])
df.loc[len(df)] = ['Mathew', 'Houston']
df.loc[len(df)] = ['Tony', 'New York']
df.loc[len(df)] = ['Jerom', 'Los Angeles']
df.loc[len(df)] = ['Aby', 'Dallas']
df.loc[len(df)] = ['Elma', 'Memphis']
df.loc[len(df)] = ['Zack', 'Chicago']
df.loc[len(df)] = ['Lisa', 'New Orleans']
df.loc[len(df)] = ['Nita', 'Las Vegas']

df.drop(df[df.apply(lambda row: 'Tony' in row.to_string(header=False), axis=1)].index, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

output:

```
     Name     Location
0  Mathew      Houston
2   Jerom  Los Angeles
3     Aby       Dallas
4    Elma      Memphis
5    Zack      Chicago
6    Lisa  New Orleans
7    Nita    Las Vegas
[Finished in 1.4s]
```

Comment: Code has been running for 15 minutes and nothing has happened @Xpeditions.

Comment: I am able  to run the sample code I shared. I edited the answer with output. Can you share your sample code ?

Comment: energy.drop(energy[energy.apply(lambda row: 'Economy 7' in row.to_string(header=False), axis=1)].index, inplace=True)
print(energy) @Xpeditions

Comment: This too worked in my environment. Can you share the dataframe, which is using ?

Comment: data is unfortunately confidential. Thanks though