# Delete row that contains a strict and specific value / int / string?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to delete every row that contains `Copy 1` in column `copy_nb`:

I tried the simple and easy function of pandas `Series.str.contains` like so:

```
df=df[~df.copy_nb.str.contains("Copy 1", na=False)]
```

Unfortunately, it is deleting the columns that contain `Copy 1`, but also `Copy 10`, `Copy 11`, etc.

Here is a sample of the data frame I want to clean:

[image]

Comment: Check the docs for `contains` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html . It is doing exactly what you are asking, as "Copy 11" does indeed contain "Copy 1". Are you looking to remove rows where the column has exactly the value "Copy 1"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to drop rows from pandas data frame that contains a particular string in a particular column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679930/how-to-drop-rows-from-pandas-data-frame-that-contains-a-particular-string-in-a-p)

Comment: You should avoid posting sample dataframes as images, post them as formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the rows where column copy_nb does not equal the value "Copy 1" like in the example below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "copy_nb": [np.nan, np.nan, "Copy 1", "Copy 2"],
    "other_column": [1, 2, 3, 4]
})

print(df)

df_copy1_removed = df.loc[df.copy_nb != "Copy 1", :]  # Here the selection happens

print(df_copy1_removed)
```

Comment: I have added an example to the proposed solution, hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
df[~df['copy_nb'].fillna('').str.contains('Copy 1')]
```