# Pandas drop rows where column contains *

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to drop all rows from this df where column 'DB Serial' contains the character *:

```
    DB Serial
0     13058
1     13069
2    *13070
3     13070
4     13044
5     13042
```

I am using:

```
df = df[~df['DB Serial'].str.contains('*')]
```

but i get this error:

```
    raise error, v # invalid expression
error: nothing to repeat
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Escape `*` by `\` because `*` is interpreted as [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> **'*'** Causes the resulting RE to match 0 or more repetitions of the preceding RE

```
df = df[~df['DB Serial'].str.contains('\*')]
print (df)
  DB Serial
0     13058
1     13069
3     13070
4     13044
5     13042
```

If also get:

> TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'

then cast column to `string`, because mixed values - numeric with strings:

```
df = df[~df['DB Serial'].astype(str).str.contains('\*')]
print (df)
  DB Serial
0     13058
1     13069
3     13070
4     13044
5     13042
```

If possible `NaN`s values:

```
df = df[~df['DB Serial'].str.contains('\*', na=False)]
```