# How to delete a row if string matches

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with a series that contains '@@@'. I want to delete rows containing this pattern.

I wrote the code for matching like this:

`df[df['employee'].str.match('@', na = False)]`

How do I delete the row if  a match is found?

Comment: if this matches, just invert the condition `df[~df['employee'].str.match('@',na=False)]`

Comment: do you want to delete the column or the row?

Comment: row i want to delete

Comment: Possible duplicate of [search for "does-not-contain" on a dataframe in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097643/search-for-does-not-contain-on-a-dataframe-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.drop`:

```
df = df.drop(df[df['employee'].str.match('@',na=False)].index)
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want to remove the rows that are filled with `@@@` in the column `employee`. If that is correct, then try:

```py
df = df.loc[df["employee"] != "@@@"]
```