# Dataframe String Value Selecting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking for a workaround in an issue I have with a pd.dataframe I am creating.
I am looking to have values in my dataframe selected based on their string values.

Here is some example code

```
'Main.loc[Main['Discrepancy Description'].str.contains('seat',case=False),'Issue']='Seats'
```

This says any time the column "discrepancy description' contains "seat" to make the value of Issues equal to "Seats".

I am curious if there's a way to exclude other parameters? As in, have the code not return "Seat" if the string says "seat belt" or something similar. Is there a way to exclude other values? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I added some sample code above that i believe clears this up a little bit more!

Comment: you could probably use `isin` instead but without a sample, I cannot test it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by using the df search up inversion (~), which looks as follows:

```
    Main.loc[~Main['Discrepancy Description'].str.contains('some cell value',na=False,case=False),'Other Column'] ='Desired value to be changed to'
```

This allowed me to quickly sort thorugh cells in excel that did not contain the parameter in the code. This was better explained in this post: [Search for "does-not-contain" on a DataFrame in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097643/search-for-does-not-contain-on-a-dataframe-in-pandas)