# Drop a row or observation by condition

Tags: python, filter, drop

Let's assume we have a dataframe df(1200, 20). Since I am only interested in 2 columns in the I will use only these in the following example

```
  index               A                       B
    1           Alex                    George
    2           Paul                   Patrick
    3           A.S.                   Nick
    3           Alice                   Dave
```

I am interested in dropping the rows that have only A.S. in my column A. Basically to obtain the following result

```
  index               A                       B
    1           Alex                    George
    2           Paul A.S.               Patrick
    3           Alice                   Dave
```

I tried the following

```
df2 = df1[df1['A'] != 'A.S.']
```

but it does not seem to do the trick. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, is `df1['A']` actually equal to `'A. S. '` in the rows that you want to discard? *Including the trailing space*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
df2 = df1[~df1['A'].str.contains('A.S. ')]
```

You may refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17097777/3397819) for the details.