# How to use str.contains() with multiple expressions in pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, regex, string, dataframe

I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to use the `str.contains()` function in Pandas, to search for two partial strings at once. I want to search a given column in a dataframe for data that contains either "nt" or "nv". Right now, my code looks like this:

```py
df[df['Behavior'].str.contains("nt", na=False)]
df[df['Behavior'].str.contains("nv", na=False)]
```

And then I append one result to another. What I'd like to do is use a single line of code to search for any data that includes "nt" OR "nv" OR "nf." I've played around with some ways that I thought should work, including just sticking a pipe between terms, but all of these result in errors. I've checked the documentation, but I don't see this as an option. I get errors like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-113-1d11e906812c> in <module>()
3 
4 
----> 5 soctol = f_recs[f_recs['Behavior'].str.contains("nt"|"nv", na=False)]
6 soctol

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'
```

Is there a fast way to do this?

Comment: *Note*: There is a solution [described by @unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48600345/9209546) which is more efficient than using `pd.Series.str.contains`. If performance is an issue, then this may be worth investigating.

Comment: Highly recommend checking out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55335207) for more info on partial string search with multiple keywords/regexes.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

They should be one regular expression, and should be in one string:

```
"nt|nv"  # rather than "nt" | " nv"
f_recs[f_recs['Behavior'].str.contains("nt|nv", na=False)]
```

Python doesn't let you use the or (`|`) operator on strings:

```
In [1]: "nt" | "nv"
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the patterns in a list, then it might be convenient if you join them by a pipe (`|`) and pass it to `str.contains`. Return False for NaNs by `na=False` and turn off case sensitivity by `case=False`.

```py
lst = ['nt', 'nv', 'nf']
df['Behavior'].str.contains('|'.join(lst), na=False)
```

Otherwise, it might be cleaner to group the alternations. For the example in the OP, that is:

```py
df['Behavior'].str.contains(r'n[t|v|f]')
```

Answer (score -2):

I try this one and it's work:

```
df[df['Behavior'].str.contains('nt|nv', na=False)]
```