# how to check whether column of text contains specific string or not in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
 job_desig             salary
 senior analyst        12
 junior researcher     5
 scientist             20
 sr analyst            12
```

Now I want to generate one column which will have a flag set as below

```
 sr = ['senior','sr']
 job_desig             salary     senior_profile
 senior analyst        12         1  
 junior researcher     5          0
 scientist             20         0 
 sr analyst            12         1
```

I am doing following in pandas

```
 df['senior_profile'] = [1 if x.str.contains(sr) else 0 for x in 
                        df['job_desig']]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using str.contains() in pandas with dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19169649/using-str-contains-in-pandas-with-dataframes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can join all values of list by `|` for regex `OR`, pass to [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and last cast to integer for `True/False` to `1/0` mapping:

```
df['senior_profile'] = df['job_desig'].str.contains('|'.join(sr)).astype(int)
```

If necessary, use word boundaries:

```
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in sr)
df['senior_profile'] = df['job_desig'].str.contains(pat).astype(int)

print (df)
           job_desig  salary  senior_profile
0     senior analyst      12               1
1  junior researcher       5               0
2          scientist      20               0
3         sr analyst      12               1
```

Soluttion with sets, if only one word values in list:

```
df['senior_profile'] = [int(bool(set(sr).intersection(x.split()))) for x in df['job_desig']]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just do it by simply using `str.contains`

```
df['senior_profile'] = df['job_desig'].str.contains('senior') | df['job_desig'].str.contains('sr')
```