# Return DataFrame item using partial string match on rows pandas python

Tags: python, string, pandas, match

I have a Dataframe of two columns, with strings in one column and lists in the other, as below:

```
      RSD_TYPE                                FILTER LIST
   0     AQ500          [N/A, Z mean, SNR mean, Dir mean]
   1    Triton  [wipe mean, Z mean, Avail mean, Dir mean]
   2  Windcube            [N/A, W mean, Q mean, Dir mean]
   3    Zephir     [Rain mean, W mean, Packets, dir mean]
```

I want to return a list based on partial string match with the elements of the column RSD_TYPE. E.G. search for which row has a partial string match with "AQ5", then return the corresponding list item from that row, in this case [N/A, Z mean, SNR mean, Dir mean].

The plan was to do this using .get_value, but first I need to have a way of returning (row) index using a partial string match. That's where I'm stuck. I know how to run a partial string match on column titles but I can't find a way to run it on the elements in that column (or the dataframe as a whole). Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Also recommend taking a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55335207).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
df[df['RSD_TYPE'].str.contains("AQ5")]['FILTER LIST']
```

Example:

```
In [3]: df
Out[3]:
   RSD_TYPE                                FILTER LIST
0     AQ500          [N/A, Z mean, SNR mean, Dir mean]
1    Triton  [wipe mean, Z mean, Avail mean, Dir mean]
2  Windcube            [N/A, W mean, Q mean, Dir mean]
3    Zephir     [Rain mean, W mean, Packets, dir mean]

[4 rows x 2 columns]
```

---

```
In [4]: df[df['RSD_TYPE'].str.contains("AQ5")]
Out[4]:
  RSD_TYPE                        FILTER LIST
0    AQ500  [N/A, Z mean, SNR mean, Dir mean]

[1 rows x 2 columns]
```

---

```
In [5]: df[df['RSD_TYPE'].str.contains("AQ5")]['FILTER LIST']
Out[5]:
0    [N/A, Z mean, SNR mean, Dir mean]
Name: FILTER LIST, dtype: object
```