# Searching a Pandas series using a string produces a KeyError

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, match

I'm trying to use `df[df['col'].str.contains("string")]` (described in these two SO questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22845959/return-dataframe-item-using-partial-string-match-on-rows-pandas-python) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350770/pandas-dataframe-select-by-partial-string)) to select rows based on a partial string match. Here's my code:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import datetime

url = "http://api.turfgame.com/v4/zones/all" # get request returns .json 
r = requests.get(url)
df = pd.read_json(r.content) # create a df containing all zone info

print df[df['region'].str.contains("Uppsala")].head()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-55bbf5679808> in <module>()
----> 1 print df[df['region'].str.contains("Uppsala")].head()

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
   1670         if isinstance(key, (Series, np.ndarray, list)):
   1671             # either boolean or fancy integer index
-> 1672             return self._getitem_array(key)
   1673         elif isinstance(key, DataFrame):
   1674             return self._getitem_frame(key)

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in _getitem_array(self, key)
   1714             return self.take(indexer, axis=0, convert=False)
   1715         else:
-> 1716             indexer = self.ix._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1)
   1717             return self.take(indexer, axis=1, convert=True)
   1718 

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.pyc in _convert_to_indexer(self, obj, axis, is_setter)
   1083                     if isinstance(obj, tuple) and is_setter:
   1084                         return {'key': obj}
-> 1085                     raise KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask])
   1086 
   1087                 return indexer

KeyError: '[ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan] not in index'
```

I don't understand the which I get a `KeyError` because `df.columns` returns:

```
Index([u'dateCreated', u'id', u'latitude', u'longitude', u'name', u'pointsPerHour', u'region', u'takeoverPoints', u'totalTakeovers'], dtype='object')
```

So the `Key` is in the list of columns and opening the page in an internet browser I can find 739 instances of 'Uppsala'.

The column in which I'm search was a nested `.json` table that looks like this `{"id":200,"name":"Scotland","country":"gb"}`. Do I have do something special to search between '{}' characters? Could somebody explain where I've made my mistake(s)?

Comment: `df['region'].str.contains("Uppsala").fillna(False)`

Comment: @behzad.nouri Could you explain what the `.fillna(False` is supposed to do? I've used it and it appears to have changed all the values to 0. `df['region'].str.contains("Uppsala").fillna(False).describe()` shows a count of 29759 and 0 for all other statistics.

Comment: can you make sure the data frame is correctly parsed? what does `df.head()` look like?

Comment: @behzad.nouri Perhaps that's the problem. I can't copy and paste the output from my IDE (Canopy) but it looks the 'cells' in under the `region` column are filled with the nested `.json` which I've pasted at end of my question in the last paragraph.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks to me like your `region` column contains dictionaries, which aren't really supported as elements, and so `.str` isn't working.  One way to solve the problem is to promote the `region` dictionaries to columns in their own right, maybe with something like:

```
>>> region = pd.DataFrame(df.pop("region").tolist())
>>> df = df.join(region, rsuffix="_region")
```

after which you have

```
>>> df.head()
                dateCreated     id   latitude  longitude         name  pointsPerHour  takeoverPoints  totalTakeovers country  id_region             name_region
0  2013-06-15T08:00:00+0000  14639  55.947079  -3.206477  GrandSquare              1             185              32      gb        200                Scotland
1  2014-06-15T20:02:37+0000  31571  55.649181  12.609056   Stenringen              1             185               6      dk        172             Hovedstaden
2  2013-06-15T08:00:00+0000  18958  54.593570  -5.955772  Hospitality              0             250               1      gb        206        Northern Ireland
3  2013-06-15T08:00:00+0000  18661  53.754283  -1.526638  LanshawZone              0             250               0      gb        202  Yorkshire & The Humber
4  2013-06-15T08:00:00+0000  17424  55.949285  -3.144777   NoDogsZone              0             250               5      gb        200                Scotland
```

and

```
>>> df[df["name_region"].str.contains("Uppsala")].head()
                  dateCreated     id   latitude  longitude          name  pointsPerHour  takeoverPoints  totalTakeovers country  id_region name_region
28   2013-07-16T18:53:48+0000  20828  59.793476  17.775389  MoraStenRast              5             125             536      se        142     Uppsala
59   2013-02-08T21:42:53+0000  14797  59.570418  17.482116      BålWoods              3             155             555      se        142     Uppsala
102  2014-06-19T12:00:00+0000  31843  59.617637  17.077094       EnaAlle              5             125             168      se        142     Uppsala
328  2012-09-24T20:08:22+0000  11461  59.634438  17.066398      BluePark              6             110            1968      se        142     Uppsala
330  2014-08-28T20:00:00+0000  33695  59.867027  17.710792  EnbackensBro              4             140              59      se        142     Uppsala
```

(A hack workaround would be `df["region"].apply(str).str.contains("Uppsala")`, but I think it's best to clean the data right at the start.)