# Python Pandas: How can I search for a string in a column?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
col1,col2
Sam,NL
Man,NL-USA
ho,CA-CN
```

And I would like to select the rows whose second column contains the word 'NL', which is something like SQL `like` command. Does anybody know about a similar command in Python Pandas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350770/pandas-dataframe-select-by-partial-string). Let `df` be your DataFrame.

```
df[df['col2'].str.contains('NL')]
```

This will select all the records that contain 'NL'.