# How to select DataFrame columns based on partial matching?

Tags: python, pandas

I was struggling this afternoon to find a way of selecting few columns of my Pandas DataFrame, by checking the occurrence of a certain pattern in their name (label?).

I had been looking for something like `contains` or `isin` for `nd.arrays` / `pd.series`, but got no luck.

This frustrated me quite a bit, as I was already checking the columns of my `DataFrame` for occurrences of specific string patterns, as in:

```
hp = ~(df.target_column.str.contains('some_text') | df.target_column.str.contains('other_text'))
df_cln= df[hp]
```

However, no matter how I banged my head, I could not apply `.str.contains()` to the object returned by`df.columns` - which is an `Index` - nor the one returned by `df.columns.values` - which is an `ndarray`. This works fine for what is returned by the "slicing" operation `df[column_name]`, i.e. a `Series`, though.

My first solution involved a `for` loop and the creation of a help list:

```
ll = []
for a in df.columns:
    if a.startswith('start_exp1') | a.startswith('start_exp2'):
    ll.append(a)
df[ll]
```

(one could apply any of the `str` functions, of course)

Then, I found the `map` function and got it to work with the following code:

```
import re
sel = df.columns.map(lambda x: bool(re.search('your_regex',x))
df[df.columns[sel]]
```

Of course in the first solution I could have performed the same kind of regex checking, because I can apply it to the `str` data type returned by the iteration.

I am very new to Python and never really programmed anything so I am not too familiar with speed/timing/efficiency, but I tend to think that the second method - using a map - could potentially be faster, besides looking more elegant to my untrained eye.

I am curious to know what you think of it, and what possible alternatives would be. Given my level of noobness, I would really appreciate if you could correct any mistakes I could have made in the code and point me in the right direction.

Thanks,
   Michele

**EDIT** : I just found the `Index` method `Index.to_series()`, which returns - ehm - a `Series` to which I could apply `.str.contains('whatever')`.
However, this is not quite as powerful as a true regex, and I could not find a way of passing the result of `Index.to_series().str` to the `re.search()` function..

Comment: Note: series filter supports regex

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your solution using `map` is very good. If you really want to use str.contains, it is possible to convert Index objects to Series (which have the `str.contains` method):

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]: 
   x  y  z
0  0  0  0
1  1  1  1
2  2  2  2
3  3  3  3
4  4  4  4
5  5  5  5
6  6  6  6
7  7  7  7
8  8  8  8
9  9  9  9

In [2]: df.columns.to_series().str.contains('x')
Out[2]: 
x     True
y    False
z    False
dtype: bool

In [3]: df[df.columns[df.columns.to_series().str.contains('x')]]
Out[3]: 
   x
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
5  5
6  6
7  7
8  8
9  9
```

**UPDATE** I just read your last paragraph. From the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), `str.contains` allows you to pass a regex by default (`str.contains('^myregex')`)

Comment: Just `df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('x')]` also works.

Comment: @Robert Smith The UPDATE was the most useful. I researched it a little bit more, and I discovered two things. Set `case=False` for a case insensitive search and `regex=True` to use regular expressions. Example: `df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('x', case=False, regex=True)]`

Answer (score 44):

Select column by partial string, can simply be done, via:

```
df.filter(like='hello')  # select columns which contain the word hello
```

And to select rows by partial string match, you can pass axis=0 to filter:

```
df.filter(like='hello', axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `df.keys().tolist()` is the thing you're searching for.

```
A tiny example:

from pandas import DataFrame as df

d = df({'somename': [1,2,3], 'othername': [4,5,6]})

names = d.keys().tolist()

for n in names:
    print n
    print type(n)
```

**Output:**

```
othername
type 'str'

somename
type 'str'
```

Then with the strings you got, you can do any string operation you want.