# Extracting groups of 3 columns from dataframe based on partial names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe containing marker positions in xyz, for 24 markers,  in every frame of a 10 second (100Hz)  timeseries. Like this:

```
    LHEE_x   LHEE_y  LHEE_z   LTOE_x   LTOE_y  LTOE_z   RHEE_x   RHEE_y 
0 -347.013  526.914  27.256 -138.267  578.015  39.859 -352.402  297.541   
1 -347.035  526.934  27.261 -138.271  578.074  39.874 -352.409  297.548   
2 -347.041  526.933  27.265 -138.260  578.073  39.898 -352.402  297.533   
3 -347.030  526.928  27.251 -138.242  578.079  39.905 -352.427  297.535   
4 -347.029  526.939  27.222 -138.244  578.072  39.915 -352.445  297.525 
.....
```

I want to extract columns that contain positions from one marker at a time (i.e. LHEE_x, LHEE_y and LHEE_z) to new dataframes, and preferrably give the new dataframes the name of the marker (i.e. LHEE).

I know I can do this "manually" by

```
LHEE=pos_xyz.iloc[:,0:3]
or    
LHEE=pos_xyz['LHEE_x','LHEE_y','LHEE_z']
```

but since I have a ton of markers this would be a hassle..

Also I would want to make a function that does this so I can use it on dataframes containing marker positions from different markers.

What would be the most efficient way to do this?
This question 
[How to select DataFrame columns based on partial matching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31551412/how-to-select-dataframe-columns-based-on-partial-matching) 
seemed promising, but I need the result to be a dataframe. 
I've tried using loops and grouping, but I can't seem to find a way that works properly.

Comment: Providing readers with a fully reproducible example would maximize your chance to get an answer. E.g. `import pandas` and provide a code which allows us to directly play with the dataframe (df), instead of obliging us to start with a copied-pasted string version of your df.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to do what you suggest, first time posting a question. I'd be happy to provide the df :)

Comment: No problem. Just remember this for the next time. BTW, jezrael's answer is very likely to be what you want. Please, [could you remove your signature ? Your "Cheers, Elise"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need create `Multiindex` by [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) column names first:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
print (df)
      LHEE                      LTOE                      RHEE         
         x        y       z        x        y       z        x        y
0 -347.013  526.914  27.256 -138.267  578.015  39.859 -352.402  297.541
1 -347.035  526.934  27.261 -138.271  578.074  39.874 -352.409  297.548
2 -347.041  526.933  27.265 -138.260  578.073  39.898 -352.402  297.533
3 -347.030  526.928  27.251 -138.242  578.079  39.905 -352.427  297.535
4 -347.029  526.939  27.222 -138.244  578.072  39.915 -352.445  297.525
```

And then create `dictionary` of `DataFrames` by `dict comprehension`:

```
dfs = {x:df[x] for x in df.columns.levels[0]}
print (dfs)
{'RHEE':          x        y
0 -352.402  297.541
1 -352.409  297.548
2 -352.402  297.533
3 -352.427  297.535
4 -352.445  297.525, 'LTOE':          x        y       z
0 -138.267  578.015  39.859
1 -138.271  578.074  39.874
2 -138.260  578.073  39.898
3 -138.242  578.079  39.905
4 -138.244  578.072  39.915, 'LHEE':          x        y       z
0 -347.013  526.914  27.256
1 -347.035  526.934  27.261
2 -347.041  526.933  27.265
3 -347.030  526.928  27.251
4 -347.029  526.939  27.222}

print (dfs['LHEE'])
         x        y       z
0 -347.013  526.914  27.256
1 -347.035  526.934  27.261
2 -347.041  526.933  27.265
3 -347.030  526.928  27.251
4 -347.029  526.939  27.222
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. Now: on to learning about dictionaries...

Comment: Glad can help, `dfs['LHEE']` is same as `df`, so same function and method works perfectly.Nice day!

Comment: This is clever ! ++ :)