# Find for a word in a each row of dataframe column and add a new column - Python

Tags: python

Suppose I have a dataframe such as follows,

```
data

    id  URL
    1   www.pandora.com
    2   m.jcpenney.com
    3   www.youtube.com
    4   www.facebook.com
```

I want to grep and find particular words in the URL and create a new column in it. Suppose I want to find youtube and facebook alone here, my ideal output would be,

```
id  URL                 host
1   www.pandora.com     None
2   m.jcpenney.com      None
3   www.youtube.com     youtube
4   www.facebook.com    facebook
```

The URLs are very complex in real data set and also the number of rows are extremely high(~4M). So I want to find 3-4 particular hosts alone and identify them by a new column.

Following is my try,

```
for i in data['URL']:
    re.search('youtube', i)
```

but I am getting,

```
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

error here. I want to create a new column in the same dataframe where I would give condition for 3-4 hosts and remaining would be none in that column. Can anybody help me?

Thanks

Comment: Check out this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350770/pandas-dataframe-select-by-partial-string) for examples of substring searches in Pandas DataFrames.

Comment: @SNygard Thanks for that link. Now I am able to split each of them into separate dataframes. But I want to create a new column based on different conditions. Can you help me in doing that?

Answer (score 1):

We'll begin by instantiating the data frame and creating a new column `host`.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3,4],
                   'URL': ['www.pandora.com', 'm.jcpenney.com', 'www.youtube.com', 'www.facebook.com']})
df['host'] = None
```

At this stage, the data frame looks like this:

```
id  URL                 host
1   www.pandora.com     None
2   m.jcpenney.com      None
3   www.youtube.com     None
4   www.facebook.com    None
```

We can create a `for` loop to search for substrings in the `URL` column. The following code writes the `df['host']` column only in the positions where the `URL` column contains the search item.

```
for item in ['youtube', 'facebook']:
    df['host'][df['URL'].str.contains(item)] = item
```

Now the data frame looks like this:

```
id  URL                 host
1   www.pandora.com     None
2   m.jcpenney.com      None
3   www.youtube.com     youtube
4   www.facebook.com    facebook
```

Note that you may get the following warning:

`C:\Anaconda3\envs\pyvizz\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py:2: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame`

The warning just tells us we're overwriting the data in some position. In our case, we're overwriting the `None` in `'host'` with `youtube` or `facebook`. So in our case the warning is safely ignored.

All of the searches you've mentioned are substring searches (check if `youtube` is a substring, etc.). However, more complicated regex searches can be done with the `findall` method.

```
import re
for item in ['youtube', 'facebook']:
    results = df['URL'].str.findall('(%s)' % item)
    df['host'][pd.Series(map(lambda x: False if len(x) == 0 else True, results))] = item
```

The `findall` applies the regular expression `(youtube)` etc to the data frame. Then we map items to `False` if `len(x) == 0`. That is, items are True if and only if the regular expression found a match. Using the True/False Series as a mask, we set all items that matched to the matched value: `youtube`.

Comment: "The warning just tells us we're overwriting the data in some position." <- ehh?  No, it doesn't.  In this case, it tells you that you're using chained indexing to set when you shouldn't, as the linked docs explain.

Comment: @DSM You're right. However, the docs include this example: `dfb['c'][dfb.a.str.startswith('o')] = 42` as a way to set values. Unfortunately, it throws the warning. If you have a better method (maybe in-place operations are a bad idea?), please edit my answer or add a new one. I could learn from that!