# Search for a partial string match in a data frame column from a list - Pandas - Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list:

```
things = ['A1','B2','C3']
```

I have a pandas data frame with a column containing values separated by a semicolon - some of the rows will contain matches with one of the items in the list above (it won't be a perfect match since it has other parts of a string in the column.. for example, a row in that column may have 'Wow;Here;This=**A1**;10001;0')

I want to save the rows that contain a match with items from the list, and then create a new data frame with those selected rows (should have the same headers).  This is what I tried:

```
import re

for_new_df =[]

for x in df['COLUMN']:
    for mp in things:
        if df[df['COLUMN'].str.contains(mp)]:
            for_new_df.append(mp)  #This won't save the whole row - help here too, please.
```

This code gave me an error:

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I'm very new to coding, so the more explanation and detail in your answer, the better! Thanks in advance.

Comment: For partial string search using multiple keywords, I recommend taking a look at [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55335207)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can avoid the loop by joining your list of words to create a regex and use `str.contains`:

```
pat = '|'.join(thing)
for_new_df = df[df['COLUMN'].str.contains(pat)]
```

should just work

So the regex pattern becomes: `'A1|B2|C3'` and this will match anywhere in your strings that contain any of these strings

Example:

```
In [65]:
things = ['A1','B2','C3']
pat = '|'.join(things)
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['Wow;Here;This=A1;10001;0', 'B2', 'asdasda', 'asdas']})
df[df['a'].str.contains(pat)]

Out[65]:
                          a
0  Wow;Here;This=A1;10001;0
1                        B2
```

As to why it failed:

```
if df[df['COLUMN'].str.contains(mp)]
```

this line:

```
df[df['COLUMN'].str.contains(mp)]
```

returns a df masked by the boolean array of your inner `str.contains`, `if` doesn't understand how to evaluate an array of booleans hence the error. If you think about it what should it do if you 1 True or all but one True? it expects a scalar and not an array like value.

Comment: Sorry @EdChum - Whilst working on my solution I didn't realise I had basically duplicated yours

Comment: @emmalg no worries, up to you what you want to do

Comment: @EdChum How would I check to see which items from the list (things = ['A1|B1|C1']) were not found at all in column 'A'?

Comment: You should post another question really

Comment: @Yuva sorry but asking questions in comments is poor form on SO, also I don't understand what you're asking. It's best to post a new question, include your raw data, code to reproduce your df, your desired result and all attempts.

Comment: @EdChum, yeah sure i understand, am doing now.  Will delete this comment, as desired. Thanks

Comment: I like this answer, but I don't think one could use it for updates, e.g.`df[df['COLUMN'].str.contains(mp)] = np.nan`, if someone wanted to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Pandas is actually amazing but I don't find it very easy to use.  However it does have many functions designed to make life easy, including tools for searching through huge data frames.

Though it may not be a full solution to your problem, this may help set you off on the right foot.  I have assumed that you know which column you are searching in, column A in my example.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : pd.Categorical(['Wow;Here;This=A1;10001;0', 'Another;C3;Row=Great;100', 'This;D6;Row=bad100']),
                   'B' : 'foo'})
print df #Original data frame
print
print df['A'].str.contains('A1|B2|C3')  # Boolean array showing matches for col A
print
print df[df['A'].str.contains('A1|B2|C3')]   # Matching rows
```

The output:

```
                          A    B
0  Wow;Here;This=A1;10001;0  foo
1  Another;C3;Row=Great;100  foo
2        This;D6;Row=bad100  foo

0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: A, dtype: bool

                          A    B
0  Wow;Here;This=A1;10001;0  foo
1  Another;C3;Row=Great;100  foo
```