# The fastest way to get filtered data checking substring value within ndarray

Tags: numpy

I have a big array of data:

```
>>> len(b)
6636849
>>> print(b)
[['60D19E9E-4E2C-11E2-AA9A-52540027E502' '100015361']
 ['60D19EB6-4E2C-11E2-AA9A-52540027E502' '100015385']
 ['60D19ECE-4E2C-11E2-AA9A-52540027E502' '100015409']
 ..., 
 ['8CC90633-447E-11E6-B010-005056A76B49' '106636785']
 ['F8C74244-447E-11E6-B010-005056A76B49' '106636809']
 ['F8C7425C-447E-11E6-B010-005056A76B49' '106636833']]
```

I need to get the filtered dataset, i.e, everything containing (or starting with) '106' in the string). Something like the following code with substring operation instead of math operation:

```
>>> len(b[b[:,1] > '10660600'])
30850
```

Comment: Would you consider parsing the second column as integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think numpy is well suited for this type of operation. You can do it simply using basic python operations. Here it is with some sample data `a`:

```
import random # for the test data
a = []
for i in range(10000):
    a.append(["".join(random.sample('abcdefg',3)), "".join(random.sample('01234567890',8))])

answer = [i for i in a if i[1].find('106') != -1]
```

Keep in mind that `startswith` is going to be a lot faster than `find`, because find has to look for matching substrings in all positions.

It's not too clear why you need do this with such a large list/array in the first place, and there might be a better solution when it comes to not including these values in the list in the first place.

Comment: Cool, indeed:
len(b[np.char.startswith(b[:,1], "1001")])

Comment: Actually I want to create my own multidimensional cube with good querying performance, just for fun and better understanding. Something like on-disk MOLAP engine. Probably I'm moving to the wrong direction, but there are my very first steps in this realm.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple pandas solution

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(b, columns=['1st String', '2nd String'])
df_filtered = df[df['2nd String'].str.contains('106')]
```

This gives you

```
In [29]: df_filtered
Out[29]: 
                             1st String 2nd String
3  8CC90633-447E-11E6-B010-005056A76B49  106636785
4  F8C74244-447E-11E6-B010-005056A76B49  106636809
5  F8C7425C-447E-11E6-B010-005056A76B49  106636833
```

**Update: Timing Results**

Using Benjamin's list `a` as the test sample:

```
In [20]: %timeit [i for i in a if i[1].find('106') != -1]
100 loops, best of 3: 2.2 ms per loop

In [21]: %timeit df[df['2nd String'].str.contains('106')]
100 loops, best of 3: 5.94 ms per loop
```

So it looks like Benjamin's answer is actually about 3x faster. This surprises me since I was under the impression that [the operation in `pandas` is vectorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350770/pandas-dataframe-select-by-partial-string). Moreover, the speed ratio does not change when `a` is 100 times longer.

Comment: Thanks, it's very informative. Performance case is very important to me.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the functions in the np.char submodule:

```
data = [['60D19E9E-4E2C-11E2-AA9A-52540027E502', '100015361'],
 ['60D19EB6-4E2C-11E2-AA9A-52540027E502', '100015385'],
 ['60D19ECE-4E2C-11E2-AA9A-52540027E502', '100015409'],
 ['8CC90633-447E-11E6-B010-005056A76B49', '106636785'],
 ['F8C74244-447E-11E6-B010-005056A76B49', '106636809'],
 ['F8C7425C-447E-11E6-B010-005056A76B49', '106636833']]
data = np.array([r[1] for r in data], np.str)
idx = np.char.startswith(data,  '106')
print(idx)
```