# How to find all rows in a dataframe that contain a substring?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, string-matching

I have one word and a Pandas dataframe with a column of string values. Now I'm trying to find the rows in that dataframe which contain that word in their string part.

I read about `extractall()` method but I'm not sure how to use it or if its even the right answer.

Comment: Is it similar to the issue referred here http://stackoverflow.com/a/11531402/5916727, you can use `df[df['column_name'].str.contains("your_string")]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using this test data (modified and borrowed from [Chris Albon](https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_hierarchical_data.html)):

```
raw_data = {'regiment': ['Nighthawks Goons', 'Nighthawks Goons', 'Nighthawks', 'Nighthawks', 'Dragoons', 'Dragoons', 'Dragoons', 'Dragoons', 'Scouts', 'Scouts', 'Scouts', 'Scouts'],
        'company': ['1st', '1st', '2nd', '2nd', '1st', '1st', '2nd', '2nd','1st', '1st', '2nd', '2nd'],
        'name': ['Miller', 'Jacobson', 'Ali', 'Milner', 'Cooze', 'Jacon', 'Ryaner', 'Sone', 'Sloan', 'Piger', 'Riani', 'Ali'],
        'preTestScore': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3, 4, 24, 31, 2, 3, 2, 3],
        'postTestScore': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70, 25, 94, 57, 62, 70, 62, 70]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['regiment', 'company', 'name', 'preTestScore', 'postTestScore'])
```

You can use this to find rows that contain the word `goons` only (I am ignoring the case):

```
df[df['regiment'].str.contains(r"\bgoons\b", case = False)]
```

Answer (score 2):

use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

```
df.mycolumn.str.contains(myword)
```

---

***demonstration***

```
myword = 'foo'
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(mycolumn=['abc', '__foo__']))

df.mycolumn.str.contains(myword)

0    False
1     True
Name: mycolumn, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jato's example.

```
In [148]: df[['Goons' in i for i  in  df.regiment]]
Out[148]:
           regiment company      name  preTestScore  postTestScore
0  Nighthawks Goons     1st    Miller             4             25
1  Nighthawks Goons     1st  Jacobson            24             94
```