# Select rows by partial string with query with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame`. 1 column (`name`) has string values. I was wondering if there was a way to select rows based on a partial string match against a particular column, using the [`DataFrame.query()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) method.

I tried:

- `df.query('name.str.contains("lu")')`. Error message: "TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed"
- `df.query('"lu" in name')`. Returns an empty `DataFrame`.

The code I use:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name':['blue','red','blue'],
    'X1':[96.32,96.01,96.05]
}, columns=['name','X1'])  


print(df.query('"lu" in name').head())
print(df.query('name.str.contains("lu")').head())
```

I know I could use `df[df['name'].str.contains("lu")]` but I prefer to use 
query.

Comment: Seems like it is not implemented yet: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8749

Comment: @ayhan Thanks. You're welcome to convert the comment into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This answer is out of date. Please check [@petobens' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53344073/2285236).

As of version 0.20.2, `query` doesn't support partial string matching. There is an [open future request](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8749) about it and one of the core developers seems to agree that it would be a nice addition.

Comment: `df.query( 'ColumnName.str.contains(\'sought_string\')')` works for me in `0.24.2` to search `sough_string` in the value stored in the column `ColumnName`. I would note that the 'engine=python' seems not needed (anymore?)

Comment: The PR for this got closed as it bring in too much magic: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/26027 However @RhoPhi answer also just works. It even works for the recently added backtick functionality: ``df.query("`column name`.str.contains('sought_string')")``. Much magic indeed.

Answer (score 16):

The issue that @ayhan refers to now shows how this can be achieved by using `query`'s python engine:

`print(df.query('name.str.contains("lu")', engine='python').head())`

should work.

Answer (score 4):

The  [petobens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2149400/petobens) solution now works with `Query` without engine spec, what increases the speed, acconding the manual.

Uses `contains` in *query* spec it's a powerful feature to handling string content because allow use *regex*.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
A = np.array(["Paulo", "Lucas", "Luana", "Larra", "BaLu","Bela"])
B = np.array([111, 222, 222, 333, 333, 777])
C = np.random.randint(10, 99, 6)
dt = pd.DataFrame(zip(A, B, C), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
dt.set_index(['A', 'B'], inplace=True)
print(dt)
print("=============")
print(dt.query('A.str.contains("Lu")'))
print("=============")
print(dt.query('A.str.contains("L(a|u)", regex=True)'))
print("=============")
print(dt.query('A.str.contains("^L", regex=True)'))  # starts with L
```

The result is

```
A   B
1.1 Paulo  57
    Lucas  49
3.3 Luana  38
    Larra  82
5.5 BaLu   37
6.6 Bela   14
=============
            C
A   B
1.1 Lucas  49
3.3 Luana  38
5.5 BaLu   37
=============
            C
A   B
1.1 Lucas  49
3.3 Luana  38
    Larra  82
5.5 BaLu   37
=============
            C
A   B
1.1 Lucas  49
3.3 Luana  38
    Larra  82
```