# Filter pandas dataframe based on defined list of strings which is present in one column

Tags: python, pandas

I need to filter `cars` pandas dataframe based on list of strings that could appear (among other strings) in one of the columns. 
So I have list of countries like this:

```
filterLocation = ['Germany','Austria','Slovenia']
```

I want to filter out all rows that contains any of these words in `Location` column of pandas dataframe.

I have this:

```
carsresult = cars.loc[~cars['adCarLocation'].isin(filterLocation)]
```

but this doesn't work for some reason..

Comment: provide sample data and expected output

Answer (score 0):

figure out the answer:

```
for country in filterLocation:
    carsML = carsML[~carsML['adCarLocation'].str.contains(country, na=False)]
```

`na=False` is neccessary if you have empty empty values othervise you'll get:

> TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: float

Comment: While your solution is working, I'd say it is not good practice. When using numpy/pandas, you should try to avoid looping as much as possible to make use of the vectorization the libraries offer. When you have 100.000 rows, the difference in runtime will be insane. Check out this alternative solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096252/use-a-list-of-values-to-select-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: @JordanKowal tried isin - it's not applicable in my case because there are other strings in cell. I need contains function which cannot be vectorized. So next best thing is list comprehension which is faster than apply and this is exactly what I used. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/2119941

Comment: My bad, hadn't seen that the column had other words in it. I found an interesting topic on the matter. Would be interesting to see if it works for you and whether it is faster. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44933071/select-rows-by-partial-string-with-query-with-pandas