# Remove row from pandas dataframe if it has 2 strings

Tags: python, string, pandas

Im looking for a way to remove a row from a pandas data frame if it contains both of the 2 strings. I can do it if it has one, but havent been able to get both to work. Below is the code i used to remove records based on 1 string, looking to change that to include another keyword

code:

```
Vikings_dataframe_cleaned2=Vikings_dataframe_cleaned[Vikings_dataframe_cleaned.TweetText.str.contains("RT") == False]
```

Strings to be excluded:
I want to check to text to make sure that it doesnt contain both @teddyb_h20 and @casekeenum7.

Example:

```
['@teddyb_h2o test test','@casekeenum7 and @teddyb_h2o are test','@casekeenum7 is the best right now']
```

The code should then produce a dataframe that looks like this:

```
['@teddyb_h2o test test','@casekeenum7 is the best right now']
```

Comment: Its a dupe, use Vikings_dataframe_cleaned[~Vikings_dataframe_cleaned.TweetText.str.contains("RT|'Your_other_string") ]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas + dataframe - select by partial string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11350770/1278112)

Comment: I just saw the message trail, can you post a sample of your dataframe and what strings do you want to exclude?

Comment: I just posted, hopefully that will help. Let me know if you need more

Comment: @Wen, lets reopen this

Comment: @J.McCraiton, 2-3 rows of dataframe will help

Comment: The dataframe only consists of the 1 column, then i add a blank column that I use in R. But i have updated the question

Comment: @Vaishali done :-)

Comment: @Wen, feel free to answer:)

Comment: For my example wouldnt I use & to make sure that it contains both of the @'s

Comment: Not sure the reason for downvote on @Wen's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['@teddyb_h2o test test','@casekeenum7 and @teddyb_h2o are test','@casekeenum7 is the best right now','test test']})

    col
0   @teddyb_h2o test test
1   @casekeenum7 and @teddyb_h2o are test
2   @casekeenum7 is the best right now
3   test test
```

Solution:

```
df[~(df.col.str.contains('@teddyb_h2o') & df.col.str.contains('@casekeenum7'))]

    col
0   @teddyb_h2o test test
2   @casekeenum7 is the best right now
3   test test
```

@Wen's suggestion, more elegant

```
df[~df['col'].str.contains(r'^(?=.*@teddyb_h2o)(?=.*@casek‌​eenum7)')]
```

Comment: I got downvote for this solution ...good luck ...upvote for yours :-)

Comment: I saw, trying to figure out. Please undelete, i will delete mine

Comment: No need , also if you do not mind you can add ..`df[~df['col'].str.contains(r'^(?=.*@teddyb_h2o)(?=.*@casekeenum7)')]` :-)

Comment: Perfect! This worked. Thanks for all your help everyone! :)

Comment: Thats even better! You should answer:)

Comment: Let us keep this site straightforward to the right answers :-)