# Merging columns with similar data from one dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table with duplicate columns that I want to join into one singular column. They share the same column names, but I want to merge any column with the same title to become one.

I have tried to to use merge, concat, among other things, but no luck.

```
data = [['a','a','c'],['a','b','d'],['a','c','c']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['col1','col2','col1'])
df
co1 col2 col1
a     a    c
a     b    d
a     c    c
```

I expect to have two columns from this point "col1 with a,a,a,c,d,c " and "col2 a,b,c,nan,nan,nan"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `stack`, then `unstack`. We will need to do a little bit more before we can unstack the data.

```
u = df.stack()
(u.to_frame()
  .set_index(u.groupby(u.index).cumcount(), append=True)
  .unstack(1)
  .sort_index(level=1)[0]
  .reset_index(drop=True))

  col1 col2
0    a    a
1    a    b
2    a    c
3    c  NaN
4    d  NaN
5    c  NaN
```

---

Another option is `groupby`, `to_dict`, and reconstruction.

```
dct = (df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1)
                          # x.values.ravel().tolist()
         .apply(lambda x: [z for y in x.values for z in y])
         .to_dict())
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dct, orient='index').T


  col1  col2
0    a     a
1    c     b
2    a     c
3    d  None
4    a  None
5    c  None
```

Comment: This worked and fix my issue. I do have a follow question. I want to understand this and not just copy, so if you have a moment how does the lambda work in this situation ?

Comment: @airbud for each group, the lambda is called, passing each group df to x. The list comprehension flattens the data and returns it.

Answer (score 1):

`melt` `groupby` with `concat`

```
d={x : y['value'].reset_index(drop=True) for x,y in df.melt().groupby('variable')}
df=pd.concat(d,1)
df
Out[39]: 
  col1 col2
0    a    a
1    a    b
2    a    c
3    c  NaN
4    d  NaN
5    c  NaN
```

Comment: Hey! Trying to advertise [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55335207/4909087), please take a look and let me know what you think.

Comment: @coldspeed that is nice answer detail and succinct, just one suggestion , maybe you can add `str.match`, since it almost dose the same thing like `str.contains`

Comment: Great! Will do.

Comment: @coldspeed and for numpy part, maybe can add `np.char.find` :-)