# How to check if a cell has a specific character in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.df[index=['2014', '2015', '2016'], columns = ['Latitude', 'Longitude'], data = ['14.0N', '33.0W'],['22.0S', '12.0E']]
```

I want to go through and check the cells in the longitude column if they have an N or an S.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Also, the definition of your dataframe is incorrect.

Comment: `df.Longitude.str.contains('N')`

Comment: I recommend taking a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55335207/4909087) to the [linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350770/select-by-partial-string-from-a-pandas-dataframe).

Answer (score 2):

I will using `endswith`

```
df.Longitude.str.endswith(('N','S'))
Out[77]: 
2014    False
2015    False
Name: Longitude, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
# Example data
df = pd.DataFrame(index=['2014', '2015'], 
           columns = ['Latitude', 'Longitude'], 
           data = [['14.0N', '33.0W'],['22.0S', '12.0E']])
print(df)
```

```
     Latitude Longitude
2014    14.0N     33.0W
2015    22.0S     12.0E
```

Check if `'N'` or `'S'` is in each row of Longitude:

```
df.Longitude.str.contains('|'.join(['N', 'S']))
```

```
2014    False
2015    False
Name: Longitude, dtype: bool
```