# How to use pandas list to search string match on a specific columns?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I wanted to search a list of string on columns, and take a boolean output if the column contains the string, i have a list.

```
dl = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.lower())

list = ['outlook', 'teamviewer']
match = len(list) 


for i in list:
   dl['Test'] = dl['User Agent'].str.contains(i , regex=False)
```

dl.head()

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55335207/4909087) help? Check the "Multiple Substring Search" subheading.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`dl['Test'] = dl['User Agent'].isin(['outlook', 'teamviewer'])`

Edit:

`df['Test'] = df['User Agent'].apply(lambda x: True if re.match('outlook|teamviewer', x) != None else False)`

Comment: getting output for outlook but not teamviewer

Comment: are you sure?? is there any capital letter or space in 'teamviewer'? Or can you post any sample data here for verification?

Comment: i am using only lower case, want a partial match like if MSoutlook should also give True.

Comment: Try edited one...

Comment: error - re not defined

Comment: Do `import re` before anything..

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with values of list joined by `|` for regex `OR`,also added flags `re.I` for ignore case:

```
import re

L = ['outlook', 'teamviewer']
df['Test'] = df['User Agent'].str.contains('|'.join(L), flags=re.I)
```

Comment: no, not work, getting all False, i am looking for partial match

Comment: @MDSAQUIBNASIRKHAN - It is weird,because it should working. Is possible add some rows of sample data to question? I think [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) should help.