# In Pandas, how to return rows which contain multiple instances of a partial string

Tags: python, pandas

This is a follow up on this stack overflow question

[Select by partial string from a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350770/select-by-partial-string-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

Which returns rows based on a partial string.

```
df[df['A'].str.contains("hello")]
```

My question is, how to return rows which contain multiple instances of a partial string.

For example, what if I want to return all rows where a particular column contains 3 instances of the partial string 'ology'. How would I do that?

Example:

```
testdf = pd.DataFrame([['test1', 'this is biology mixed with zoology', ], ['test2', 'the cat and bat teamed up to find some food'], ['test2' , 'anthropology with pharmacology and biology']])

testdf.head()


>0  1
>0  test1   this is biology mixed with zoology
>1  test2   the cat and bat teamed up to find some food
>2  test2   anthropology with pharmacology and biology

testdf = testdf[testdf[1].str.contains("ology")]
testdf.head()

>0  1
>0  test1   this is biology mixed with zoology
>2  test2   anthropology with pharmacology and biology
```

What i am looking for is rows with 3 instances of 'ology' , so it would only return the last row

```
>2  test2   anthropology with pharmacology and biology
```

Comment: Could you add a small example dataset so we can visually see what you mean.

Comment: I added an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to use `str.contains`, you may use `pat` as follows:

```
testdf[1].str.contains('(.*ology.*){3}')

Out[29]:
0    False
1    False
2     True
Name: 1, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case you don't want to use `str.contains` but [`str.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) to find the amount of occurences of `ology`:

```
testdf[testdf['Col2'].str.count('ology').eq(3)]
```

Output:

```
    Col1                                        Col2
2  test2  anthropology with pharmacology and biology
```

**Note** I called your columns `Col1` and `Col2`

Comment: This seems to be removing rows that seem to qualify. I'll make a more specific example, but I am specifically looking for '\n', or line breaks if it makes a difference. Perhaps I should try '*\n*'?