# Drop columns if rows contain a specific value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am starting to learn Pandas. I have seen a lot of questions here in SO where people ask how to delete a row if a column matches certain value.

In my case it is the opposite. Imagine having this dataframe:

[image: Dataframe]

Where you want to know is, if any column has in any of its row the value `salty`, that column should be deleted, having as a result:

[image: Dataframe 2]

I have tried with several similarities to this:

```
if df.loc[df['A'] == 'salty']:
   df.drop(df.columns[0], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

But I am quite lost at finding documentation onto how to delete columns based on a row value of that column. That code is a mix of finding a specific column and deleting always the first column (as my idea was to search the value of a row in that column, in ALL columns in a `for` loop.

Comment: @cs95 I'm afraid you misread the question...

Comment: @IanS Indeed the code was confusing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Perform a comparison across your values, then use `DataFrame.any` to get a mask to index:

```
df.loc[:, ~(df == 'Salty').any()]
```

If you insist on using `drop`, this is how you need to do it. Pass a list of indices:

```
df.drop(columns=df.columns[(df == 'Salty').any()])
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['Mountain', 'Salty'], 'B': ['Lake', 'Hotty'], 'C': ['River', 'Coldy']})
df
          A      B      C
0  Mountain   Lake  River
1     Salty  Hotty  Coldy
```

```
(df == 'Salty').any()
A     True
B    False
C    False
dtype: bool

df.loc[:, ~(df == 'Salty').any()]
       B      C
0   Lake  River
1  Hotty  Coldy
```

```
df.columns[(df == 'Salty').any()]
# Index(['A'], dtype='object')

df.drop(columns=df.columns[(df == 'Salty').any()])
       B      C
0   Lake  River
1  Hotty  Coldy
```

Comment: This: `df.loc[:, ~(df == 'Salty').any()]`worked just fine! Thank you!

Comment: @cs95 What if I wanted to check for a particular substring instead of a specific string?

Comment: @Mega_Noob You might find my answer on substring matching useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350770/select-by-partial-string-from-a-pandas-dataframe/55335207#55335207

Answer (score 3):

The following is locating the indices where your desired column matches a specific value and then drops them. I think this is probably the more straightforward way of accomplishing this:

`df.drop(df.loc[df['Your column name here'] == 'Match value'].index, inplace=True)`

Comment: this was helpful, i was able to use a variation of this in a list comprehension to cull a lot of unwanted columns quickly. `[df.drop(df.loc[df['col name'] == item].index, inplace=True) for item in some_list]`

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possibility:

```
df = df.drop([col for col in df.columns if df[col].eq('Salty').any()], axis=1)
```