# How can I exclude columns in a Daraframe if the content of a row contains a specific substring?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56754831/drop-columns-if-rows-contain-a-specific-value-in-pandas) touches upon the problem that I am facing. However, instead of excluding columns based on an exact string match, I want to exclude columns if a particular substring matches.

For example, in the image below, I would like to filter out columns A and C because they contain the substring 'is'

How would I go on about doing this? I replaced `df.loc[:, ~(df == 'Salty').any()]` from @cs95's answer to `df.loc[:, ~(re.findall('/\w+(?:is)\w+/', df)).any()]` but this gives me a

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Any help would be appreciated!

**Input**

```
|---------------------|------------------|----------------|----------|
|                     |         A        |          B     |   C      |
|---------------------|------------------|----------------|----------|
|          Value      |        Red       |    Green       |Blue      |
|---------------------|------------------|----------------|----------|
|          12         |  HotisGood       |    Warm        |isGood    |
|---------------------|------------------|----------------|----------|
```

**Output**

```
|---------------------|--------------|
|                     |        B     |   
|---------------------|--------------|
|          Value      |   Green      |
|---------------------|--------------|
|          12         |  Warm        |
|---------------------|--------------|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
cols = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('is').any())
df.loc[:, ~cols]
```

Output:

```
           B
Value  Green
12      Warm
```

Comment: Hi! I included the sample input table and output table - is the image not visible/corrupted? Should I re-upload it?

Comment: @Mega_Noob no, images are not encouraged, see a guide to [ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: Understood, thank you. I will update the question right away - jbtw the output is the exact opposite of what I want (which is to exclude the columns that are being shown now and keep everything else)

Comment: @Mega_Noob please see updated. As you also see, the text data helps me debug my code and reproduce your expected outcome easily.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I'll keep formatting in mind for the future