# Pandas, find and delete rows

Tags: python, pandas

Been searching for a while in order to understand how to do this basic task without any success which is very strange.

I have a dataset where some of the rows contain '-', I have no clue under which columns these values lie.

How do I search in the whole dataset (including all columns) for '-' and drop the rows containing this value?

thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56754831/drop-columns-if-rows-contain-a-specific-value-in-pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit more robust than wwnde's answer, as it will work if some of the columns aren't originally strings:

`df.loc[~df.apply(lambda x: any('-' in str(col) for col in x), axis = 1)]`

If you have data that's stored as datetime, it will display as having `-`, but will return an error if you check for inclusion without converting to `str` first. Negative numbers will also return True once converted to `str`. If you want different behavior, you'll have to do something more complicated, such as

`df.loc[~df.apply(lambda x: any('-' in col if isinstance(col, str) else False for col in x), axis = 1)]`

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['-', 2, '-', 0],
                   [3, 4, '-', 1],
                   ['-', '-', '-', 5],
                   ['-', 3, '-', 4]],
                  columns=list('ABCD'))
```

then df looks like

```
df = 
    A   B   C   D
0   -   2   -   0
1   3   4   -   1
2   -   -   -   5
3   -   3   -   4
```

you can replace all '-' with nan values with `df.replace()` function. you can do `help(df.replace)` do learn more

```
df = df.replace('-', np.nan)
df=
A   B   C   D
0   NaN 2.0 NaN 0
1   3.0 4.0 NaN 1
2   NaN NaN NaN 5
3   NaN 3.0 NaN 4
```

to drop columns with these '-' you can drop them with `df.dropna(how='all')`

Answer (score 0):

Please Try

```
df[~df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('-')).sum(1).gt(0)]
```

**How it works**

```
    df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('-'))#Gives a boolean return of where there is '-'

   df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('-')).sum(1)# Sums the boolean in each row. 

   df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('-')).sum(1).gt(0)#tests and returns true where the value was greater than zero, meaning anywhere where there was '-' returned at least 1

   ~df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('-')).sum(1).gt(0)- Reverse the above, giving you rows where there was no '-'


   df[~df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('-')).sum(1).gt(0)]# Mask the rows where there was no'-' into a dataframe
```