# python : How to delete the column which contains specific word or string like 'No data' i.e. removing columns which has any specific string

Tags: python-3.x

```
  Rat Rat 1 Rat 2
0 jkl No    jkl
1 ghj No    jkhj
2 mmm No    jkl
3 klj No    oo
4 kkk No    jkk
```

I want to remove the column which has string 'No' and the output should have only rows Rat and Rat 2

Comment: how did you create these columns? are they read from `csv`? using some external library like `pandas`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drop columns if rows contain a specific value in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56754831/drop-columns-if-rows-contain-a-specific-value-in-pandas)

Comment: Possibly an answer can be derived from [Delete a column from a Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411544/delete-a-column-from-a-pandas-dataframe),