# Extracting rows with substring containing whitespace after + in pandas df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, substring

I want to get all the rows in `df` whose `path` column contains a substring `new+ folder`. This question [Select by partial string from a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350770/select-by-partial-string-from-a-pandas-dataframe) and the answer by cs95 has been very helpful for substrings like `new+` or `fol` but the results are not correct when I search

`new+ folder`.

```py
>>>dft = pandas.DataFrame([[ '/new+folder/'], ['/new+ folder/']], columns=['a'])
index     path
0         `/new+folder/`
1         `/new+ folder/`
```

Now testing with `query`

```py
>>>print(dft.query('a.str.contains("new+")', engine='python').head())

a
0   new+folder
1  new+ folder
```

```py
print(dft.query('a.str.contains("new+ ")', engine='python').head())
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a]
Index: []
```

```py
>>>print(dft.query('a.str.contains("new+ f")', engine='python').head())
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a]
Index: []
```

Testing with `contains`:

```py
>>>dft[dft['a'].str.contains('new+')]
a
0   new+folder
1   new+ folder
```

```py
>>>dft[dft['a'].str.contains('new+ ')]
a
```

```py
>>>dft[dft['a'].str.contains('new+ f')]
a
```

How can I get the error resolved that comes when there is a  after a `+` or I feel special characters?

Pandas 0.24.2
Python 3.7.3 64-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `+` is special regex character, need escape it if need working solution with `query`:

```
print(dft.query('a.str.contains("new\+ ")', engine='python').head())
               a
1  /new+ folder/
```

Solution with `regex=False` here not working:

```
print(dft.query('a.str.contains("new+ ", regex=False)', engine='python').head())
```

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'

If want filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) working both solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below `str.contains` solution:

```
>>> dft[dft['a'].str.contains('new+ f', regex=False)]
               a
1  /new+ folder/
>>>
```

`+` is a regex quantifier, whereas pandas will think you want it as a regex quantifier, so do `regex=False` to stop making pandas think of it as a regex quantifier.

**Timings:**

```
>>> timeit(lambda: dft[dft['a'].str.contains('new\+ f')], number=10000)
7.6474129006344995
>>> timeit(lambda: dft[dft['a'].str.contains('new+ f', regex=False)], number=10000)
7.188472783778991
>>>
```

It looks like mine is a bit faster.