# How to filter a pandas dataframe using multiple partial strings?

Tags: python, pandas

I understand how to filter a dataframe in pandas using a single or two partial strings:

```
final_df = df[df['Answers'].str.contains("not in","not on")]
```

I got the help from this link:
[Select by partial string from a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350770/select-by-partial-string-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

However I am unable to extend the filtering to more than two partial strings.

```
final_df = df[df['Answers'].str.contains("not in","not on","not have")]
```

If I try, I get the following error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'

How do I tweak if I have to extend the filtering based on multiple partial strings? Thank You.

Comment: Use `df['Answers'].str.contains("not in|not on|not have")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with `|` for multiple search 
elements:

```
mask = df['Answers'].str.contains(regex_pattern)
final_df = df[mask]
```

To create the regex pattern if you have the search elements use:

```
strings_to_find = ["not in","not on","not have"]
regex_pattern = '|'.join(strings_to_find)
regex_pattern 
'not in|not on|not have'
```

Comment: it would be great if you add how to get regex with `|`. using `join`