# Filter if one element of a column fits the conditioning pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data table that contains several keywords in one column and I would like to filter if one of the keywords registers with my query.

Assume this example DataFrame:

```py
    import pandas as pd 
    testdata = pd.DataFrame({"key":["This is", "just a", "meaningless and boring test example"], "value" : [2,3,4]})
```

This should result in a DataFrame like this:

```
key                                 | value
--------------------------------------------
This is                             | 2
just a                              | 3
meaningless and boring text example | 4
```

I'd now like to filter for occurrence if some keywords are part of my keywords. i. e. show all rows that contain "This" and "meaningless". In code I would expect something to work like:

```py
    testdata.query('key in ["This", "meaningless"]')
```

Comment: Use `df[df['key'].str.contains("This|meaningless")]`

Comment: Or `L = ["This", "meaningless"]` and then `df[df['key'].str.contains('|'.join(L))]`

Comment: thx, if someone wants to use the (in my opinion) more readable query function: testdata.query('key.str.contains("This|meaningless")')

Comment: check in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55335207) answer.