# finding part of string in panda list

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas `dataframe` in which I have 1300 brain parts with 21 columns of information about them. In there is a `structure_id_path`, a tree-like structure of brain regions. 
I want to find every structure_id_path that contains e.g. '315' in it.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('/home/anja/Schreibtisch/Master/vonIsa/structure_tree_safe_2017.csv')

df[df.structure_id_path == '/997/8/567/688/695/315/184/526157192/']
```

When I do it like that I find exactly that one brain part with that specific `structure_id_path`.

But if I want to find every `structure_id_path` that contains `315`, it returns an empty dataFrame, because it can't find 315.

```
isocortex = '315'
x = structure_list[structure_list['structure_id_path'] == isocortex]
```

Is there a method to find it, like *315 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select by partial string from a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350770/select-by-partial-string-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df[df.structure_id_path.str.contains('/315/')]
```

Comment: @Anja: If it answers your question, please accept the answer by clicking the small check next to it which then turns green.

Comment: I have now the problem that it also finds '1315' but I only want to find exactly '315'. Do you know how I can do this?

Comment: @Anja Since your numbers always come between "/", I added those to the string in search